# How to find regions that satisfy this inequality?

Tags: equation-solving

1. I am new to *Mathematica* and would like to find the set  $$\{ (x,y)
       \in \mathbb{R}^2: (3x+y\exp(xy))(x-a) + (6y + x \exp(xy))(y-b) < 0
       \}$$  for some constants $a$ and $b$. How can I do this? **Added**: Is the set empty when a=-1.0643 and b=0.150?
2. My actual question may be more difficult. For this function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, defined as
   $$ f(x,y) := (3x+y\exp(xy))(x-a) + (6y + x \exp(xy))(y-b) $$ I would like to know its
   range $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$, or better yet $f(\mathbb{R}^2 - \{(a,b)\})$, or as close as possible. Can it
   be done in *Mathematica* as well?

Comment: Is the set Finite? If so use the function FindInstance or use Solve or NSolve:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindInstance.html?q=FindInstance&lang=en

If the set is not finite, then please clarify what you mean by "finding the set".

Comment: @Searke: I have no idea if the set is finite, or empty. That is part of my questions too.

Comment: Can you describe what you would like to do as you would do it by hand on a chalkboard or with a different piece of software?

Comment: If you are asking me how I do it by hand, I can tell you I will be stuck. If you are asking me why I want to know the result, my part 2 explains that, I think.

Comment: Please also include the expressions in correct Mathematica syntax.  It is appreciated if you include formatted math for readability, but it is important to also have directly copyable code.

Answer (score 9):

[Please please please...post actual cut-and-pastable code.]

Here is a method that is, unfortunately, impractical. But it sometimes gives results if you are patient.

```
isEmpty[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := Module[{finst},
  finst = 
   FindInstance[(3*x + y Exp[x*y])*(x \[Minus] a) + (6*y + 
         x*Exp[x*y])*(y \[Minus] b) < 0, {x, y}];
  If[ListQ[finst],
   If[Length[finst] == 0, True, False]
   , $Failed]
  ]

In[306]:= isEmpty[1, 3]

Out[306]= False
```

Here is a start on a method that uses contpur plotting. One must settle for a finite range on {x,y} for this; I use -+10 for both.

```
isEmpty2[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := Module[{cplot},
  cplot = 
   ContourPlot[(3*x + y Exp[x*y])*(x \[Minus] a) + (6*y + 
         x*Exp[x*y])*(y \[Minus] b) == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    ContourShading -> False, Frame -> None]
  ]
```

It just gives a picture but i guess those better versed in Mathematica's Graphics might be able to extract at True/False therefrom. It would of course not be a guaranteed resutl, since plotting uses numeric approximation methods.

It gives a nice result for a=-4, b=-1.

[image]

--- edit ---

A comment asks about a specific set of inputs for {a,b}. Not one to duck such a test, I'll show a result with FindRoot. Here we find an {x,y} pair for which the expression of interest is negative (equal to -0.2), by setting y first to 0. I did this because the contour plot indicated there was a negative region in that general vicinity.

```
In[339]:= FindRoot[((3*x + y Exp[x*y])*(x - a) + (6*y + 
        x*Exp[x*y])*(y - b) /. {a -> -1.0643, b -> -.15, 
     y -> 0.}) == -.2, {x, .1}]

Out[339]= {x -> -0.0634401}
```

--- end edit ---

Comment: Thanks! Is the set empty when a=-1.0643 and b=0.150?

Comment: @Tim No, not empty. isEmpty2[1.0643, .15] indicates a small ovaline contour. Or something. (I don't suppose "ovaline" is a word.)

Comment: @Daniel: a is negative. If it is nonempty, could you give an element of the set?

Comment: @Tim see edited response.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks! (a is negative and b positive). May I ask what "In[306]:= isEmpty[1, 3]" and "Out[306]= False" mean? Is the first one run the function isEmpty and return the false, true or failed value to the variable In[306]? What does 306 mean in both?

Comment: @Tim (I'll get it right eventually.) When b is +0.15 I get a root x -> -0.0706475. The In[306]/Out[306] is just Mathematica's way of denoting a computational input and evaluated result.

Answer (score 6):

To get an indication of the region where your function is negative you could use `RegionPlot`. For example

```
ineq[x_, y_, a_, b_] := 
  ((3 x + y Exp[x y]) (x - a) + (6 y + x Exp[x y]) (y - b))

Manipulate[
 Show[RegionPlot[ineq[x, y, a, b] < 0, {x, -8, 20}, {y, -5, 20}, 
   ImagePadding -> 20, PlotPoints -> 30]],
 {a, 0, 10},
 {b, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]