# Output of plots from within Do[ ] Command

Tags: functions, syntax

I am wondering why the following does not plot the way it's written and exactly how does the `Do[]` function operate? I think I could be using it incorrectly.

```
In[1]:= u[x_, t_] := (1/2) (Exp[-(x + t)^2] + Exp[-(x - t)^2])
        Do[
           Plot[u[x, k], {x, -5, 5}, 
           AxesLabel -> {x, u}, 
           PlotRange -> {0, 1}],
           {k, 0, 3}
          ]
```

---

### EDIT

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a = 1;
b = 1;

ϕ[ξ_, ν_, t_] := 
  Sum[(((5*(-1 + (-1)^j)*(-1 + (-1)^i))/(j*i*Pi^2))*
      Cos[(1/Pi^4)*Sqrt[i^4*Pi^4 + j^4*Pi^4]*t])*Sin[i*Pi*ξ]*Sin[j*Pi*ν], {i, 1, 
    10}, {j, 1, 10}];

Do[Print[Plot3D[ϕ[ξ, ν, m], {ξ, 0, a}, {ν, 0, b}, Mesh :> Automatic, 
   PlotLabel :> StringJoin["Surface Plot of Solution at t = ", ToString[m]], 
   ColorFunction :> {"BlueGreenYellow"}]], {m, 0, 10, 2}]
```

Comment: Strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5682/121

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is that since version 6 of Mathematica, the `Plot` *returns* its output just like any other function.  It does not print is as a [side effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29).  `Do` is meant to be used with operations that have side effects and simply discards the output, so you never see the plot.

You can either use `Table`, which collects the values in a list:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note how you get a *list* of graphics objects.  Graphics are expressions like any other, they're simply shown using a special formatting.  You can always see their internal structure by using `InputForm` on them or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> on the containing cell.

Or you can use `Print` explicitly:

```
Do[Print@Plot[u[x, k], {x, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {x, u}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {k, 0, 3}]
```

---

**Note:**  If as @JM noted, you are trying to animate the plot, use [`Animate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Animate.html):

```
Animate[Plot[u[x, k], {x, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {x, u}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {k, 0, 3, 1}]
```

Comment: I have a strong feeling OP's code was taken from an old *Mathematica* book, and the intention was to animate the plot; you might thus want to mention `Animate[]`.

Comment: @J.M.: No this was not the intention, I was trying to find a more convenient way of making multiple plots when necessary by the the computer do the work for me in a more programmatic fashion rather than copy/paste several `Plot` commands or use `Manipulate` over a certain range (parameter). But that does sounds interesting now that you bring that idea up. Thanks `:)`

Comment: @nightowl You can use `Row`/`Column`/`Grid` to arrange the plots in a nicer layout

Comment: @night owl: I see; as I said, it's exactly how animations were done in old *Mathematica*, so that's what I thought you were doing. Then indeed, `Table[]` is what you want (though that too was used for producing animations as well for subsequent exporting).

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks! I will look into how to arrange them nicely using the suggestions you've given.

Comment: @J.M.: Oh really, hmm interesting. Did not know that. See, the only thing I do not like about using `Table` for graphics is that it includes the braces `{ }` around the graphic and has the commas to separate them. Is this shown in the graphic itself when exporting the figure? Oh and by the way, thanks again for the `Animate` suggestion. First time using it. Usually I go with `Manipulate`. I quite like it.
`u[x_, t_] := 1/2 (Exp[-(x + t)^2] + Exp[-(x - t)^2])
Animate[Plot[u[x, m], {x, -5, 5},PlotRange :> {0, 1},PlotStyle :> {Thick, Blue},AxesLabel :> {x, u},AspectRatio :> 1],{m, 0, 5, 0.025}]`

Comment: @J.M.: BTW, nice Avatar on your homepage. Pretty awesome! `:)`

Comment: @night owl: "See, the only thing I do not like about using Table for graphics is that it includes the braces" - well, you will have to look into `Grid[]`/`GraphicsGrid[]` as Szabolcs suggests. You can use it with `Table[]` (and possibly `Partition[]`) so that things are laid out nicely.

Comment: @J.M.: Yes, that's exactly what I use to get the job done -> `GraphicsGrid`, but I have to try out `Table` w/ `Partition` to see how that looks. `:)` Thanks

Comment: @Szabolcs: How do would I implement `GraphicsGrid` to the problem? Or what is the most efficient way to organize the graphics? I will edit the question because it is too much code to fit here in the comments. Or should I make this a new question?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [`DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DisplayFunction.html), something before the time of graphic input/output of version 6. The following line prints the same way as Szabolcs's 2nd example.

```
Do[Plot[u[x, k], {x, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {x, u}, PlotRange -> {0, 1},
   DisplayFunction -> Print], {k, 0, 3}]
```

`DisplayFunction -> f` wraps the actual output of any `Graphics` function (`Plot` here) into `f`. This way one can directly send the plot to any pipe, for example to a stream or file. If you are version 6+ though, the best solution is to use `Table`, just as Szabolcs has said.

Comment: Thanks for that alternative method. Could you read the last comment under `Szabolcs` post. I want to try and use `GraphicsGrid` with the `Do` command. Also, another concern came up. What is the most efficient way of using the iterator for the `Do` command. Because at most it take three arguments, e.g. `Do[expr,{k,min,max,step-size}]`. But what if you have a function such as $\phi[\xi_,\nu_,t]$, and you want to plot for value of time say: $t=0,0.3,0.7,0.10,0.14,0.16$. As you can notice, the time instances (steps) are not by the same amount, so how could you account for this when using

Comment: the `Do` command. Or is there something you can add.. Or would you just have to input the times in manually for a case like this?

Comment: @nightowl the syntax you are looking for is `Do[f[x], {x, {0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.10, 0.14, 0.16}}]` -- this also works for `Table`.  Also realize you could use `Scan` or `Map`, e.g. `Scan[f, {0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.10, 0.14, 0.16}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Oh my! Thank You. This helps alot! `:)`. So could you ("usually") input `list` in place of an iterator if you have several values to input with staggering increments of time? Now only to get `GraphicsGrid` to work in junction with it and that will complete my handy toolbox for the moment. `:)` Do each graphic have a internal name associated with them or could one be assigned to them. Because I know that `GraphicsGrid[{{g_11,g_12,...},...}]` needs to have variables (functions) hence -> ($g_{11},g_{12}$) assigned for input to create the 2-D grid.

Comment: @nightowl I'm not sure what you're trying to do but it's quite possible you don't realize you can pass a table of graphics objects directly to `GraphicsGrid`:  `GraphicsGrid[ 
 Table[Plot[k Sin[x] + x, {x, 0, 3 Pi}], {k, 4}] ~Partition~ 2 ]`  (Here I generate four plots with `Table`, split it into a 2x2 table with `Partition`, and pass the result to `GraphicsGrid`.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Okay, so is that saying k*Sin[x], so is it plotting:
{Sin[x],2 Sin[x], 3 Sin[x], 4 Sin[x]}? I don't want to change the original function by a multiplying scalar due to the Table iterator. If that's what it is doing from `{k,4}`. Could it be done on something like what I put in the question underneath **EDIT**? But keeping `Do[ ]` and not using `Table[ ]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is getting a bit lengthy for comments:

> What is the most efficient way of using the iterator for the Do
>   command. Because at most it take three arguments, e.g.
>   Do[expr,{k,min,max,step-size}]. But what if you have a function such
>   as ϕ[ξ,ν,t], and you want to plot for value of time say:
>   t=0,0.3,0.7,0.10,0.14,0.16. As you can notice, the time instances
>   (steps) are not by the same amount, so how could you account for this

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
Do[f[x], {x, {0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.10, 0.14, 0.16}}]
```

This also works for Table.  In simple cases such as this example you could use `Scan` or `Map`:

```
Scan[f, {0, 0.3, 0.7, 0.10, 0.14, 0.16}]
```

> Do each graphic have a internal name associated with them or could one
>   be assigned to them. Because I know that
>   GraphicsGrid[{{g_11,g_12,...},...}] needs to have variables
>   (functions) hence -> (g11,g12) assigned for input to create the 2-D
>   grid.

No, the elements of the table given to `GraphicsGrid` do not need to be assigned to symbols first.  Here is an example using the function given in your question:

```
u[x_, t_] := (1/2) (Exp[-(x + t)^2] + Exp[-(x - t)^2])

plots =
 Table[
   Plot[u[x, k], {x, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {x, u}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}],
   {k, 0, 3}
 ];

Partition[plots, 2] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I don't see what `Scan` does. It must be something internally but does not return anything to the screen. And `Map` just seems to do something weird like `{Cos[x][0],Cos[x][0.3],...}` with f being Cos[x], from your example shown. And I'm glad to see that it works for `Table`, but my question was how to get it to work with the example I provided in the question underneath **EDIT** using the `Do` command.

Comment: @nightowl `Scan` is to `Map` as `Do` is to `Table`.  Try: `Scan[Print, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]`