# How to Plot inside a Do loop?

Tags: plotting

Why does this not give me any plots?  It should give five plots.

```
Do[Plot[x^n, {x, 1, 2}], {n, -2, 2}]
```

If I remove the `Plot` from the `Do`, it works, but I want a series of plots.  This is just an example, I'm trying to do something more complicated, but this illustrates the problem.

How can I create a series of plots?

Comment: Just write `Table` instead of `Do`

Comment: Or use the nasty `Do[Print@Plot[x^n, {x, 1, 2}], {n, -2, 2}]`

Comment: All, I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate but I can't find it just yet.

Comment: @verbeia, [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7212/output-of-plots-from-within-do-command) perhaps?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries - yes, thanks! Now why couldn't I find it? I feel a bit guilty picking up the rep, but I think my answer is more succinct than the ones to that question.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html):

> Unless an explicit `Return` is used, the value returned by `Do` is `Null`

In other words, unless you create a side effect by assigning something to some expression name, e.g. using `Set` (`=`), `Do` doesn't "do" anything. It evaluates expressions but does not return them.

As mentioned in comments, there are many alternative - and superior - ways to get what you want.

```
Table[Plot[x^n, {x, 1, 2}], {n, -2, 2}]

Plot[x^#, {x, 1, 2}] & /@ Range[-2, 2]  (* Map *)

Array[Plot[x^#, {x, 1, 2}] &, 5, -2]
```

Comment: I'm also sure it's a dup, but can't find it. +1 anyway.