# How to print strings and numbers inside a While?

Tags: string-manipulation, printing

I'm trying to print the dimensions of some Vector spaces, but I want to print strings with it so I can read the results more easily. I tried this

```
n = 0; While[dimF[n] > 0, StringForm["dimH_`1`=`2`", n, dimH[n]]; n++]
```

But it isn't printing anything.

Comment: Wrap Print[] around your StringForm[] and see what happens.

Comment: While (and Do, and For) loops in Mathematica don't have an output by default, so you need to either explicitly Print the data (as @Bill) suggested or generally more useful accumulate the data to some list so that you can reference it computationally later (be it with Append, or whatever)

Comment: André, I think this topic is the answer, what is your opinion? [Output of plots from within Do loop](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7212/5478)

Comment: Also [`Echo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html?q=Echo).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem doing this

```
n = 0; 
While[dimF[n] > 0,  Print["dimH_", n, "=", dimH[n]]; n++]
```