# Plotting graphics as ASCII plots

Tags: plotting, visualization

I'm occasionally in a situation where I have to use *Mathematica* on the terminal. I'd like to visualize the solutions I get from `NDSolve`, but when I use `Plot`, *Mathematica* just shows `-Graphics-` instead of trying to plot anything. I decided to write my own function for this:

```
AsciiPlot[functionsl_, {t_, tmin_, tmax_}] := Module[
{buffer, pts, width, height, ymin, ymax, s, functions, function, 
allpts},
width = 77; height = 24;
buffer = Table[" ", {height}, {width}];
If[Head[functionsl] === List, functions = functionsl, 
functions = {functionsl}];(*ensure functions is a list even if of length 1*)
allpts = Table[{x, (functions[[j]]) /. t -> x} // N, {j, 
 Length[functions]}, {x, tmin, tmax, (tmax - tmin)/width}];

(*Min and max of all y's across all functions to plot*)
ymin = Min[allpts[[1 ;;, 1 ;;, 2]]];
ymax = Max[allpts[[1 ;;, 1 ;;, 2]]];
s = (ymax - ymin)/(tmax - tmin);

For[i = 1, i <= Length[functions], i++,
function = functions[[i]];
pts = allpts[[i]];

(*I think it is bad form to declare a function inside a module, but it needs the variables and it is a pain to pass them all as arguments*)
set[point_, letter_] := ( 
  buffer[[height - point[[2]] + 1, point[[1]]]] = letter;);
PickLetter[slope_] := 
 Piecewise[{{"-", -.65 s < slope < .65 s}, {"/", .65 s <= slope < 
     3.5 s}, {"|", 
    3.5 s <= slope},  {"\\", -3.5 s < slope <= -.65 s}, {"|", 
    slope <= -3.5 s}}, "*"];
ScalePoint[p_] := 
 Round[{(p[[1]] - tmin)*(width - 1)/(tmax - tmin) + 
    1, (p[[2]] - ymin)*(height - 1)/(ymax - ymin) + 1}];

Map[set[ScalePoint[#], 
   PickLetter[D[function, t] /. t -> #[[1]]]] &, pts, 1];](*end for each function*)
Map[Print[StringJoin[#]] &, buffer, 1];]
```

How can I extend this to plot axes as well? 
My strategy (forcing even one function to be a list) for plotting multiple functions to mimick the native `Plot[]`'s behavior seems pretty unintuitive. Is there a better way?

Also, I would have preferred a function that could work on a `Raster` object, which would allow me also to use things like `ParametricPlot` and even the 3D plots with no extra effort. I couldn't think of a way to get around needing the derivative short of trying to fit curves to the rasterized image and plotting those. Any tips?

Comment: "I'd like to visualize the solutions I get from `NDSolve`, but when I use `Plot`, *Mathematica* just shows `-Graphics-` instead of trying to plot anything." - you'll want to look into [`$Display`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Display.html) and [`$DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$DisplayFunction.html)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719898/graphics-in-command-line-mathematica-7

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're stuck with the terminal, but have access to X11 and Java, then I suggest using `` JavaGraphics` ``, which allows you to display plots, but continue to work in the terminal. This was also [answered here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2914/5), but I learnt it from from [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens).

If you really want an ASCII plot, I suggest using the `` Terminal` `` package that gives you an ASCII plot:

```
<< Terminal`
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

It also works in the front end (although, I don't know why anyone would use it in the FE):

[image]

Comment: Wow! I had no idea this existed. Unfortunately, I get `Can't open display ":0.0"` when I try it. I am connecting to a linux machine that is at runlevel 3 (no X11 or any graphical interface) using ssh.

Comment: @user141603 `JavaGraphics` won't work without X11, but if even `Terminal` (which doesn't require `JavaGraphics`) doesn't work for you, then I don't know... please try using only `Terminal` in a fresh kernel

Comment: I am running CentOS 6.3. I reboot, login at the "localhost login:" prompt, run "math", type "<<Terminal`" and get that error... Very odd.

Comment: @user141603 It doesn't work for me either... on runlevel 3 Mathematica even produces a segfault.

Comment: @sebhofer I've never gotten a segfault. Are you using CentOS?

Comment: @user141603 No, I'm on Linux Mint Debian.

Comment: As cool as this is, I can't get it to work in Mathematica 10.0.3

Comment: Currently (version 11), on the [open cloud online](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/), this prints something like `255<>255<>255<>255...` instead.