# Why won't Mathematica plot my function?

Tags: plotting

I'm using a theoretical answer found on the official Wolfram site as a reference to ensure my code isn't faulty (even though I'm fairly confident that my original code is half decent).

```
sol = DSolve[y'[x] + x*y[x] == Cos[x^2], y, x]
```

> ```
> {{y -> Function[{x}, E^(-(x^2/2)) C[1] + 1/2 E^(-(x^2/2)) Sqrt[π/10]
>          (Sqrt[1 + 2 I] Erfi[Sqrt[1/2 - I] x] + Sqrt[1 - 2 I] Erfi[Sqrt[1/2 + I] x])]}}
> ```

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1}], {x, -7, 7}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The output shown of the Wolfram site actually shows a nice looking plot. On my display all I get is `-Graphics-`. There is no plot.

Why is this?

Comment: Are you using Mathematica from a terminal or are you using the graphical interface?  If you are using the graphical interface, have you tried restarting Mathematica?  Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: Also, go to Preferences -> Evaluation, click Reset to Defaults, restart and try again.

Comment: Possibly an RPi user who started `wolfram` instead of `mathematica`???

Comment: I'm using the 9.0.1 kernel

Comment: Can you plot anything? eg `Plot[x,{x,0,1}]` .. ?

Comment: @user12289 You did not answer my question though: are you using Mathematica from the command line (terminal) or are you using its graphical interface?  If you don't answer these questions then we simply can't help you.

Comment: I'm assuming I'm using the terminal because there is no GUI that I see here. The software package I received from a friend just has a shortcut with the Wolfram logo. I double click on it, and I get what appears to be a sophisticated text file that allows me to do rudimentary computation.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your _Mathematica_ session?

Comment: (duplicate) You can use JavaGraphics or ASCII graphics for the terminal. See my answer here: [Plotting graphics as ASCII plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13963)