# Under OS X, is there a way to view graphics output when running in the command line?

Tags: graphics, mac-os-x, command-line

Being a long time unix shell person, I prefer Mathematica's command line interface, over the notebook.  (command history, etc...)

It just learned that on OS X, the cli is available as MathKernel.

What I'm wondering now is, is it possible to open graphics (and/or animations, sounds, etc) result, from within the command line?

```
In[16]:= Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]

Out[16]= -Graphics-
```

I would like to be able to view output #16.

Comment: You need to load ``<<JavaGraphics` ``. See also my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2914/5) (that question and title should probably rewritten)

Comment: @rm-rf Strangely, when using ``<<Terminal` ``, I get garbage output on OS X.

Comment: @Szabolcs Terminal is for ASCII graphics and it [has worked for me](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13963/5)

Comment: @rm-rf I thought it has worked for me too, but I'm getting [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xfd7jes3nkbg5t/Screenshot%202014-05-21%2010.13.49.png) now.  Have you tried on Mavericks?

Comment: @Szabolcs You're right, that's what I get too on Mavericks. Nothing comes to mind immediately as to what could be wrong...

Comment: @rm-rf, sorry, didn't see your comment before I answered. My bad.

Comment: @Szabolcs same output here on Mavericks 10.9.3.

Comment: You are going to lose a lot by sticking to the command line interface though.  You'll probably end up getting frustrated and concluding that Mathematica is not very good.  I'd advise you to learn to use the notebook interface properly instead.  Not only is it the proper way to use Mathematica (it's desgined to be used this way), I personally find it far superior to *any* command line interface when doing interactive scientific computing.  What you're saying sounds like this to me: "I'm used to working with screwdrivers, so I want a screwdriver with a tough handle that can hammer in this nail."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a FrontEnd to generate actual images, but you don't have to use the notebook interface.  You can actually do all of this from a standalone kernel.  (You must be logged in to a system that allows you to launch GUI applications, though.)

For example:

```
In[5]:= g=Plot[Sin[x],{x,-Pi,Pi}];                                              

In[6]:= Export["testplot.png",g]                                                

Out[6]= testplot.png

In[7]:= UsingFrontEnd[SystemOpen["testplot.png"]]
```

You first create the object you want to see (in this case expression g).  Then you pass it to Export.  Export will launch the FrontEnd as a service to render the expression, and then the Kernel will convert it to the format specified in Export and save it to disk.  You can then view it using SystemOpen.  This technique will also work with animations (you will need to use an export format like QuickTime).

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered my question.  This, and  the info about `<<JavaGraphics\`` and `<<Terminal\`` are exactly what I am looking for.   (fwiw, I also get noise with terminal graphics under Mavericks, but I feel like that can probably be sorted out.)

Comment: @ChristopherCole Just curious: why does the kernel have to launch the FrontEnd to export? (I assume that's just images?) It seems odd that if we are writing data to a file that the kernel couldn't do that by itself.

Comment: Ultimately, you need something to render `Graphics[...directives, primitives, and options...]`. The FrontEnd isn't the only program that knows how to do this; `JavaGraphics\`` in the Kernel can render those primitives and directives it understands. However, since V6, Graphics, like formatted text and equations, are _really_ box expressions and therefore subject to styles and style inheritance. The FrontEnd knows how to resolve these styles, so asking the FrontEnd to perform the render means that the exported graphic will have nearly the same appearance as in a Notebook.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a windowing system, the following before evaluating a graphic should work.

```
<<JavaGraphics`
```