# How to view an image from command line?

Tags: command-line

I'm running mathematica in command line mode, but I need to view a graph/image, so I'd like to open an image with an X11 window to inspect an image:

[image]

Is there an easy way or built-in command to to this?

**Update:**

This differs from the [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48239/under-os-x-is-there-a-way-to-view-graphics-output-when-running-in-the-command-l) Mr. Wizard references, because the terminal is running remotely in ssh:

[image]

This is how I do it in the terminal usually:

[image]

but doesn't work from within mathematica:

[image]

Comment: What does `$DisplayFunction` return on the command line?

Comment: One easy way to do it is to export the file, then have the system open it.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Okn2s.png

Comment: Would you please clarify how this differs from [(48239)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48239/121)?

Comment: $DisplayFunction is Identity

Comment: Then you can modify it so that graphical output is redirected to e.g. `stdout`. What OS are you on?

Comment: Running Ubuntu in EC2

Comment: How do you ssh into the remote machine? Can you display any image? ssh -X perhaps?

Comment: you could probably do `StartProcess` and pipe the graphic to an external process w/o writing a file. It will depend on the specific display utility though.

Comment: Subbing StartProcess for RunProcess immediately crashes x11

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Might be relevant, but this is something I use that uses [`StartProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartProcess.html) and [`ProcessConnection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProcessConnection.html).

```
xShow[expr_] := Module[{pr = StartProcess[{"display", "png:fd:0"}]},
  WriteLine[ProcessConnection[pr, "StandardInput"], 
    ExportString[expr, "PNG"]];
  ]
```

then

```
Plot3D[Sinh[x]Sinc[y],{x,0,Pi},{y,0,Pi}]//xShow
```

results in:

[image: Screenshot]

This pipes the output to the program [display](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/display.php).

I wanted to use this as the [`$DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$DisplayFunction.html), but that doesn't cover things like `GeoGraphics` or other functions that don't use `$DisplayFunction`, and `Plot` does some strange doubling (you first get a blank plot and then a plot with the function).

A clever use of `$Post` could be used rather than my `Postfix` use.

Answer (score 6):

As long you've set X11 forwarding correctly `JavaGraphics` should work just fine.  I.e, `ssh -Y remote` followed by

```
<<JavaGraphics`
Plot3D[Sin[x],{x,0,2Pi},{y,0,1}]
```

in the remote kernel.

Answer (score 3):

I always use Mathematica from the command line and have usually done display by setting the file init.m in Library/Mathematica/...Kernel/ to the script below.  This works on a Mac; it writes the graphics to a pdf file, then displays it.

Unfortunately, in Math 11 some of the graphics displays no longer use $DisplayFunction (e.g. ListPlot, Show, ...) and I haven't found a good workaround yet.  But the code below works well for Plot, Plot3D, etc.

```
(*-----------Graphics for command line Mathematica ----------------*)
(*  Install this file in Math../Configuration/Kernel/init.m *)
(*  It may be necessary to create this directory *)
(*  Writes images as PDF files to /tmp/math.xx; then uses Preview to show them *)

Begin["System`Private`"]  ;
MaxImages = 100;
ImageNumber = 0;
Unprotect[ $DisplayFunction]; Clear[ $DisplayFunction]; $Display = {};
$DisplayFunction := Block[{fid,str},
fid="/tmp/math."<>ToString[ImageNumber]<>".pdf";
str=Export[fid, #,"pdf"];
Run["open -a Preview "<>fid<>" &"];
ImageNumber = Mod[ImageNumber+1,MaxImages];
        #]&;
End[];
```