# Using Terminal` (ASCII plots) in Wolfram 12

Tags: plotting, packages, kernel, compatibility, raspberry-pi

I was interested in exploiting the Terminal` package, as demonstrated in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13961/plotting-graphics-as-ascii-plots), to show some ASCII plots straight through the terminal of my Raspberry Pi Model 3 B+. However, it doesn't seem that I can get a plot to show when using the package either in the terminal or *even in the front-end*. Here's what happens in either case when I try to replicate a simple example:

```
In[1]:= << Terminal`                                                            
 -- Terminal graphics initialized -- 

In[2]:= Plot[Sinc[x],{x,0,20},PlotRange->All]                                   
#
StringJoin[MapThread[System`ConvertersDump`RasterDataPacket[#"#", #"#", #"#", #"+", ColorFunction -> #"+"] & ]]

Out[2]= -Graphics-
```

The package seems to load fine, the stuff between the In[2] line and the Out[2] line is stuff Mathematica outputted (I didn't type it), and the graphics the system outputs in both cases are fully formatted correct plots; just not in ASCII. **Is the package broken, or am I missing something**?

Comment: Unfortunately that answer is from 2012 - the package might not have been touched since then. :( It also seems like there are come comments on later versions that also found that it didn't work.

Comment: If the package is broken due to failure of updating it, as it seems based on your analysis, would that be considered a bug or just unsupported functionality? I think the idea of making ASCII plots in the terminal is really neat, and would be happy to report this issue to Mathematica as a bug if it might get someone to update it in the future.

Comment: Since that package is undocumented, it's not considered supported functionality and presumably any response to your support request will be through that lens. However, this really does seem like cool functionality, so maybe it would be worth sending a message to support as a feature request rather than a bug report.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an approach to fix the code behind `` Terminal` `` - Execute the following code to restore the functionality of the package:

```
<< Terminal`

ExportString["", "TTY"];
DownValues@System`Convert`BitmapDump`ExportTTY = DownValues@System`Convert`BitmapDump`ExportTTY /.
   {
    TextStyle -> LabelStyle,
    HoldPattern[pre : (data_ = _[___, gr_, "ColorReductionPalette" -> crp_, _, opts_])] :>
     (
      pre;
      data = Replace[
        ImageData@ColorQuantize[
          Image[data, "Byte"],
          crp,
          FilterRules[{opts},
           Options@ColorQuantize]
          ],
        Thread[First /@ crp -> Range@Length@crp],
        {2}
        ]
      )
    };
```

Now:

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
(*   #                                                                            
     ##                                                                           
     ##+                                                                          
     ##++                                                                         
     ## ++                                                                        
     ### +                                                                        
     ##  ++                                                                       
     ##   +                                                                       
     ##   ++                                                                      
     ##    +                                                                      
     ##    ++                                                                     
     ##     +                                                                     
     ###    ++                                                                    
     ##      +                                                                    
     ##      ++                                                                   
     ##       +                                                                   
     ##       ++                                                                  
     ##        +               ++++++     #                  #                    
     ## #   #  +#   #  #   # ++#+  #++#+  #   #   #  #+++#+++#   #  #   #   # ++# 
   ###############################################################################
     ##          +         ++           +++++  +++++            ++++++++++++      
     ##           +       ++               +++++++                 + + +          
     ##           ++   +++                                                        
     ##            ++++++                                                         
     ##                                                                           *)
```

Looking at the [`$DisplayFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$DisplayFunction.html) set by `` Terminal` ``, we see that it uses `ExportString[#,"TTY"]` to generate the ASCII plot. That function in turn uses the `"PNM"` image format to do the actual conversion. It turns out that this format has lost some functionality at some point, specifically for the `"ColorReductionPalette"` option. This option was used to convert the image into a version with only six gray levels, which were then converted into the different ascii characters. Since that option no longer exists, we replicate it by inserting a call to [`ColorQuantize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorQuantize.html), followed by some post-processing. It should be noted that this does not produce exactly the same output as in older versions, presumably something in the rendering/quantization code got updated at some point.

Answer (score 10):

**Note** After looking through the referenced python code, it stands to reason that all of the tools are available from within Mathematica.  I have yet to fully debug this sub-answer.  You can take advantage of `$DisplayFunction` to estimate what `Terminal` did:

```
$DisplayFunction = 
 ExportString[
   StringJoin /@ 
    Flatten /@ (ImageData@
        ColorConvert[Rasterize[#, RasterSize -> 100], 
         "Grayscale"] /. {1. -> " ", _Real :> "x"}), "Text"] &
```

**Inspiration** *Original answer is below*

It looks like `Terminal.m` uses `ExportString[...,"TTY"]` in a `$DisplayFunction` call, which is not (no longer?) a valid export type.  A rudimentary hack involves some python code.

```
wget raw.githubusercontent.com/RameshAditya/asciify/master/asciify.py
```

Towards the end of the python script, you'll note that there is an option to grab images from the web.  This library does not appear to be installed by default on the RPi so I removed that 3-4 lines of code as it is irrelevant here.  Now creating an asciiplot requires 2 steps:

```
o=Plot[Sinc[x],{x,0,10},AspectRatio->1/2,ImageSize->100,Axes->False,Frame->{True,True,False,False},FrameTicks->{{0,10},{-0.2,1}}];
Export["out.png", o];
Run["python asciify.py out.png"];
```

[image]

One needs to play around with image features (aspect ratio, size, tick marks) to make this work reasonably.  The nice feature is that it is raster-based so one can in principle view any graphical mathematica output in the terminal.

FWIW, the python code seems straightforward enough that it can probably be incorporated into the newish language connectors that are available.

Comment: This worked well for me (I had the same error as the OP). I just ran the first piece of script you give as a line of code within Mathematica 13, then Plot[Sinc[x],{x,0,20},PlotRange->All]  and I got the right output.