# Handling failed FindRoot calls

Tags: programming, equation-solving, numerics

I want to handle `FindRoot` calls which did not converge (e.g "thrown" error message `FindRoot::cvmit`)

```
sols = Table[FindRoot[some equations dependant in a, startSolutions], 
    {a, minA, maxA, stepSize}]
```

For some, `FindRoot` will not converge (3000 iterations). Is there a way to define the entry of `sol` in this case to e.g. `NAN`?

EDIT:
Is there a possibility to break further evaluation of the `Table` call, if `Check[]` returns a defined value?

`Break[]` is only allowed in `For[]`, `While[]` and `Do[]` - so do I have to encapsulate my `FindRoot` call in an extra loop and construct the table by hand?

e.g.:
`(** apply solver and Check[] if jacobian gets singular **)`

`sols = {};`

`For[Alpha = minAlpha, Alpha <= maxAlpha, Alpha += stepSize, 
  Append[sols, Check[solver, {Alpha, Break[]}, {FindRoot::jsing}]]];`

Unfortunately this does not work...

Comment: Well, the wording of your question has part of a potential solution... what do you do when someone [`Throw`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Throw.html)s something at you? You [... ;)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Catch.html). Perhaps you could try working with this new information and try to update your question with what you've tried and where you're getting stuck? You might also want to take a look at `Check`

Comment: @R.M Hmmm, I'm not seeing a `Duck` function...

Comment: @Brett Champion: the best (only) Mathematica humor I've ever read?

Comment: @Brett Champion A very clear Duck function is in the responses to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/how-to-find-regions-that-satisfy-this-inequality/2906#2906

Comment: Please ask a separate question on breaking from a `Table` instead of editing this old question.  It's not possible to break from a `Table` *and preserve all results comuted so far* (it's possible to break using `Throw` and discard results).  I'd recommend using `Sow`/`Reap` in a `Do` loop instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `Check` to return an alternate result and use `Quiet` to avoid the messages that you are expecting anyway.  Here's an example:

```
Quiet[Table[Check[x /. FindRoot[x^2 - c, {x, 1}],
  "NaN", {FindRoot::lstol, FindRoot::jsing}], {c, -5, 5}],
  {FindRoot::lstol, FindRoot::jsing}]

(* Out: 
  {"NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 7.45058*10^-9, 
   1., 1.41421, 1.73205, 2., 2.23607}
*)
```

One important note is to make sure that the `Check` is inside the `Quiet`, and not the other way around.  If `Quiet` is inside `Check` the message will be "quieted" before it is seen by `Check` and so you won't get `"NaN"`.