# Checking if an Expression Falls within a Range

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is there a simple way in Mathematica to check under what conditions an expression (involving multiple variables) falls within a given range? For example, say I had a real-valued function f(x,y,z), where x,y,z are real numbers. I want to find the set S such that f(x,y,z) > 0 whenever (x,y,z) are contained in S. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You should specify what kind of function is `f` and what you expect to get, since the question is too general for a constructive answer. If `f` is a polynomial or a transcendental function, if you expect an exact solution, a numerical approximation or to get only some idea how that region looks like, in this case look e.g. at answers to this question : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/how-to-find-regions-that-satisfy-this-inequality

Comment: As it stands now, the question is its own answer, because the set S can be defined by $S = \{\vec{r}\in\mathbb{R}^3\vert f(\vec{r})>0\}$.

Answer (score 6):

Tutorial [**The Representation of Solution Sets**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheRepresentationOfSolutionSets.html) is a great start. Generally it depends on **`f(x,y,z)`** if you can find a solution. In many particular cases you can find reduced forms. Quoting the tutorial:

> Any combination of equations or inequalities can be thought of as implicitly defining
>   a region in some kind of space. The fundamental function of [**`Reduce`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) is to 
>   turn this type of implicit description into an explicit one.

Examples of usage:

**1)** A multivariate polynomial inequality:

```
Reduce[x^2 - 3 y + z^2 > 0, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

[image]

**2)** Systems of polynomial equations and inequalities can always be reduced:

```
Reduce[x^2 + y z >= 0 && x + 2 y <= 3 + 1 && y z > 7, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

[image]

*Mathematica* has also related visualizations and some interesting functions, like [**`SemialgebraicComponentInstances`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SemialgebraicComponentInstances.html) that "gives at least one sample point in each connected component of the semialgebraic set defined by the inequalities". This example finds at least one sample points inside a solid and visualizes it.

```
ineqs = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 7 x y z < 1 && x^2 + y^2 > 2 z^3 + 5/4 && 
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 3;  r = 1.7; 
pts = SemialgebraicComponentInstances[ineqs, {x, y, z}]; 
Show[{RegionPlot3D[ineqs, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]], Mesh -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 35], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[{x, y, z} /. pts]}]}, 
 SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

To check points indeed belong to solid:

```
 And @@ (ineqs /. pts)
```

> True

Comment: For algebraics, in addition to `SemialgebraicComponentInstances[]`, the function `CylindricalDecomposition[]` might also be of interest.