# Turn list of edges into a polygon function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, geometry

I have a list of coordinates that define the edges of a polygon and I would like to get a function defining the area Inside out if it (The polygon is convex and the points are in order)

So that for example: 
`List[{0, 2}, {4, 2}, {.5, 0}]`

Becomes:
`Boole[(y < 2 && 7y > 4x-3 && Y > 2-4x)]`

I found the Polygon function to accept lists but I don't know how to turn it into a function.
I guess there is some easy way to do that as it's a quite common thing but I fail to find it.

Comment: The type of example you give will work only for convex polygons. Is that a fair assumption to make in your application?  If so, may we also assume the vertices have already been sorted in the order they appear around the polygon's boundary, and that the sorting follows a conventional orientation (such as keeping the interior of the polygon always to the left)? A solution for non-convex polygons can be obtained but would require more work (equivalent to triangulating them). Is it possible you only need some procedure to solve the point-in-polygon problem?

Comment: Very related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924171/geo-fencing-point-inside-outside-polygon

Comment: @whuber As long as it has no self intersection it need not be convex. One can determine the sense of the inequalities without anything as hardcore as triangulation. This does however assume the points are given in a connected order.

Comment: @whuber Yes, the polygons are convex and the points are in order

Comment: is this related to your earlier question?  There are better ways of finding areas and centroids of polygons..

Comment: @Daniel The example output is an intersection of half-planes, which can describe only a convex figure.

Comment: @george2079 It relates to some degree but I am curious how to do this at all

Comment: @whuber Sorry, yes, you are right. I had convinced myself otherwise in a momentary delusion of adequacy.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/how-to-check-if-a-2d-point-is-in-a-polygon

Comment: @george2079 I think you didn't understand my question: The points are at the edge of the polygon, they are always inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your points are in order then you could probably create a linear function for each point-pair. In this linear equation you replace the `Equal` by `LessEqual` to get not the points *on* the line but all points on the left side too.

The next creates exactly this closed half-plane by using the *two-point form* of a line

```
halfplane[{{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}}] := (y - y0) (x1 - x0) <= (y1 - y0) (x - x0)
```

What follows is, that you create pairs of your points and for each pair you calculate an in-equation. The region that fulfills all those in-equation should be your polygon. Note, that you have to `Append` the first point again at the end of your list to create the final, closing line.

```
createFunc[data_] := 
 And @@ Map[halfplane, Partition[Append[#, First[#]] &@data, 2, 1]]

data = {{0, 2}, {4, 2}, {.5, 0}};

RegionPlot[createFunc[data], {x, -1, 5}, {y, -1, 3}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Your function for this is

$$4 (y-2)\leq 0\land -3.5 (y-2)\leq -2 (x-4)\land -0.5 y\leq 2 (x-0.5)$$

which gives `True` for all points inside your polygon. Compare this to the display of the polygon created by your points

```
Graphics[Polygon[data], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your answer is spot on, but strictly speaking, `lineeq` is an inequality describing a half-plane, rather than the equation of a line.

Comment: @m_goldberg Hmm, I wanted to make clear that the half-planes come directly from the two-point form of a line. Now that you say it, I see that my naming is misleading.

Comment: nice -- suggest you edit to point out the assumptions, polygon must be convex and points must be ordered counter clockwise.