# how to interactively select points inside certain region in a plot

Tags: plotting, dynamic

Very often I encounter a situation that I want to select some points inside certain areas of a plot. For example,

```
p1 = Graphics[Point[Table[{Random[], Random[]}, {200}]]]
```

will give a plot. If I use MMA's drawing tool to draw a region in the plot,

p2=[image]

how I get the plot dynamically updated so that it shows only the points inside that region?

---

Here is my attempt. 
I use the function `inPolyQ` by [rm -rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf) at [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9417/1364) to test whether the points is inside the region or not.

```
lines = First[Cases[p2, Line[x_] :> x, \[Infinity]]];
pts = First[Cases[p2, Point[x_] :> x, \[Infinity]]];
inPolyQ[poly_, pt_] := Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] =!= 0
slctPts = Select[pts, inPolyQ[lines, #] &];
Graphics[{Point[slctPts], Line[lines]}, AbsoluteOptions[p1]]
```

the out put is
[image]

I have two problems:

1. How can I change it to a efficient function that can do all this dynamically on a plot(or may density plot), and with the option to output the selected data points?
2. There is a problem that sometimes I actually select more points than I want. Like in the example, there are two points outside the region are also selected. Is there a way to solve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see the duplicate question above. The answers there solve this exact problem. As a side note, you could also use ``Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ`` (with the same syntax). I mentioned this in a comment under my answer

Comment: @rm-rf thanks for point this out, I tried to search some words, but this didn't come up. It's exactly what I'm looking for. You were so fast!

Comment: @xslittlegrass WoW, I like your method to choose region using drawing tool, it's much more flexible to use linesegment or freehandline than polygon. And so smart to extract `lines` and `pts` from the plot. Why didn't you post an answer to that question?