# How do I calculate the area of a polygon given its coordinates?

Tags: geometry

I have a polygon:

```
Polygon[{{0, 200 }, {200, 100}, {500, 300}, {100, 700}}]
```

How can I figure out its area? The [docs page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Polytopes/ref/Area.html) does not have any example.

So far I've reached this point with no success:

```
Needs["Polytopes`"]
Area[Polygon[{{0, 200 }, {200, 100}, {500, 300}, {100, 700}}]];
```

Concerning `Area`, the documentation states:

> Area[polygon]
>   $\  \ \ \ \ $ gives the area of polygon polygon, when the edges of polygon have unit length.

So it is possible that my question really should be **how to set unit length on edges of polygon?**

Comment: Area of polygon = 1/2 apothem * perimeter * height

Comment: `Area` command was introduced on July 9th, 2014; `Area[Polygon@pts]`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basing on undocumented function introduced by [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/) in [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22543/5478):

```
pts = {{0, 200}, {200, 100}, {500, 300}, {100, 700}};

Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
PolygonArea[pts]
```

> ```
> 155000.
> ```

Usage of undocumented functions is usualy useful but keep in mind that it may not work with future versions or with all cases. On the other side, it may work. One just can't be sure and trust them too much. ;)

Comment: when I tried
pts = {{5, 2}, {4, 1}, {1, 3}};

Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
PolygonArea[pts]
I got `-2.5`. I don't understand.

Comment: @minthao_2011 the order does matter. Try `PolygonArea[Reverse@pts]`. If it is only a matter of clockwise or anticlockwise order you can use `Abs`.

Answer (score 22):

I prefer `PolygonArea` myself, but for version 7 users, there's [this function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5964/5) by Mr.Wizard for non-intersecting polygons:

```
polygonArea = 
 Compile[{{v, _Real, 2}}, 
   Block[{x, y},
    {x, y} = Transpose[v]; 
    Abs[x.RotateLeft[y] - RotateLeft[x].y]/2
   ]
 ]
```

It gives the same answer as the undocumented built-in (as it should).

Comment: This algorithm is given in [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html).

Comment: polygonArea is 3 times fast in my test. And even more with `CompilationTarget->"C"`

Comment: Heh -- I wrote this ten years ago.  I'm glad it's still serviceable.  +1 of course. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Let's see... 10 years ago, I did not know a single programming language. In fact, I had not written a single line of code in any language and had not even considered using a computer for programming :D

Comment: By the way, you're making me feel old. :-p

Answer (score 14):

I cannot resist.  Writing the code rm -rf posted was one of my first *Mathematica* programming exercises from over eleven years ago.  (Boy, time flies.)  Here's a copy of the old Notebook, which I kept, and yes, these are the actual notes I wrote myself.  (I do not attest to their present accuracy, only their historical record.)

> ---
>
> ### Polygon
>
> Area of non-self-intersecting polygons, described by a set of {x,y}
>   points, using the direct Determinant method. In this version, emphasis
>   was placed on conciseness of code.
>
> ```
> polyarea = Abs@Tr[Det /@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1]]/2 &;
> ```
>
> Again, the Determinant method, but in a semi-explicit form that is
>   somewhat more efficient.
>
> ```
> polyarea = Abs[Tr[#*#4 - #2*#3 & @@@ Partition[Flatten[#], 4, 2, 1]]/2] &;
> ```
>
> These are compiled versions of the prior two functions, respectively.
>   Of note is that the version using Det is only marginally improved with
>   Compile, while the other becomes several times more efficient. 
>   Viewing the compiled code will show that Det is apparently not
>   actually compiled (it is explicit).  Also note the changes that were
>   made to each function to conform to the constraints of Compile.
>
> ```
> polyarea = 
>   Compile[{{v, _Real, 2}}, 
>    Abs@Tr[Det /@ Partition[Append[v, v[[1]]], 2, 1]]/2];
>
> polyarea = 
>   Compile[{{v, _Real, 2}}, 
>    Abs[Tr[#[[1]]*#[[4]] - #[[2]]*#[[3]] & /@ 
>        Partition[Flatten[Append[v, v[[1]]]], 4, 2]]/2]];
> ```
>
> *Updated May 26, 2002.*
>
> In this function the Determinant method is optimized using
>   Dot-products.
>
> ```
> polyarea = 
>   Block[{x, y, R = RotateLeft}, {x, y} = Thread@#; Abs[x.R@y - R@x.y]/2] &;
> ```
>
> This compiled version of the Dot-based function is nearly twice as
>   efficient as the non-compiled version. Amazingly, this makes it over
>   30 times as fast as the direct Determinant approach.
>
> ```
> polyarea = 
>   Compile[{{v, _Real, 2}}, 
>    Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = Transpose@v; 
>     Abs[x.RotateLeft@y - RotateLeft@x.y]/2]];
> ```
>
> ---

By the way, these days I would use `Module` for the non-compiled version; I used to abuse `Block` rather badly.

Comment: My first _Mathematica_ notebook should be burned and the ashes of the bytes scattered across the Pacific Ocean.

Comment: @rm-rf Not proud of them, eh? ;-p  Mind you this wasn't my first attempt at *Mathematica* programming, rather one if my earliest exercises.  I don't think I kept any of my first attempts, and besides, at the beginning I thought *Mathematica* was just a big calculator; I didn't realize you could *program* with it right away.

Comment: @rm-rf p.s. I'm now digging through the archives trying to find the *oldest* thing I have that vaguely qualifies as programming.

Comment: @rm-rf I may have found it; my first use of anything besides an explicit formula followed by `Solve` or `Plot`:  `Table[Rationalize[N[Pi],10^-d],{d,1,5}]` <--- look Ma, Programming!! lol

Comment: Heh, I don't have my first ones, but it probably was something along the lines of `For[... For[... mat[[i,j]] = RandomReal[];]]` :P

Comment: @rm-rf Lol. This was exactly how I used *Mathematica* until I joined this site earlier this year.

Answer (score 7):

In version 10, many graphics primitives, including `Polygon`, can be treated as [geometric regions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricComputation.html).  Use [`RegionMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html):

```
poly=Polygon[{{0, 200 }, {200, 100}, {500, 300}, {100, 700}}];

RegionMeasure[poly]
(* 155000 *)
```

Comment: ``Region`RegionMeasure[poly]`` works in version 9.0.1.0 (possibly in earlier versions, too) -- +1.