# Finding the area bounded by a logspiral curve and two straight lines

Tags: geometry

I'm facing some trouble with finding the area of a region which is described by x-y coordinates (or line equations) and a curved line represented by logspiral. I tried my best in coming up with the following illustration below to show what I mean:

[image]

- B = Angle between Horizontal (at x2,y2) and the line described by r
- r = Equation of the curve region, described by: r = a*exp(B)
- a = Value of r when B = 0
- (x,y) = Coordinates of the vertices

I understand that I could find the intersection of the 2 half-spaces using 2 equations describing the 2 straight line portions (say using `RegionIntersection`), but I'm not too sure how I could incorporate the logspiral equation to get the bounding area using `RegionMeasure`.

I'm inclined to convert the logspiral equation to parametric form for this purpose, but I have no idea how to move on from there.

I would really appreciate any help or advice regarding this problem, I have been losing some sleep thinking about this question.

Comment: You can construct a `ParametricRegion` of two parameters, one the angle `B`, and other a multiplier of `r` from 0 (which is `(x2, y2)` to 1, which is the spiral. The problem with this construction is that Mathematica is still unlikely to be able to compute analytic area for this region, although `ParametricRegion` allows it to be defined...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand what is known and what is not, but assuming that you know `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2` and  `a` you can do (with *v8*, I assume *v10* makes it much easier):

```
{x1, y1} = {0, 0}; {x2, y2} = {2, 3};
angle[v1_, v2_] := N@ArcCos[(First@v1*First@v2 + Last@v1*Last@v2)/(Norm@v1*Norm@v2)]
eqn[k_, l_, a_, x_, α_] := k + l*a*Exp[x*α]

kk[l_, a_] := k /. Solve[eqn[k, l, a, x1, angle[{x2 - x1, y2 - y1}, {a, 0}]] == y1, {k}]
ll[a_] := l /. Solve[eqn[kk[l, a], l, a, x2 + a, angle[{x2 - x1, y2 - y1}, {a, 0}]] == y2, {l}];
pts[a_] := Join[First@
   Cases[Plot[kk[ll[a], a] + ll[a]*a*Exp[x*angle[{x2 - x1, y2 - y1}, {a, 0}]], {x, x1, x2 + a}], Line[x_] :> x, ∞], 
   {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x2 + a, y2}}]
```

Here I'm using [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48094/1356) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31243/1356) to make sure the `Polygon` will have the right shape:

```
SignedArea[p1_, p2_, p3_] := 
  0.5 (#1[[2]] #2[[1]] - #1[[1]] #2[[2]]) &[p2 - p1, p3 - p1];
IntersectionQ[p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_] := 
  SignedArea[p1, p2, p3] SignedArea[p1, p2, p4] < 0 && 
   SignedArea[p3, p4, p1] SignedArea[p3, p4, p2] < 0;
Deintersect[p_] := Append[p, p[[1]]] //. {s1___, p1_, p2_, s2___, p3_, p4_, s3___} /; 
      IntersectionQ[p1, p2, p3, p4] :> ({s1, p1, p3, 
       Sequence @@ Reverse@{s2}, p2, p4, s3}) // Most;
fpts[a_] := Deintersect[pts[a]];
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
Abs@PolygonArea[fpts[2]]
```

> ```
> 6.18614
> ```

```
Block[{a = 2}, 
 Graphics[Polygon@fpts[a], Axes -> True, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Point[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x2 + a, y2}}], 
    Line@pts@2, Green, Dashed, Line@fpts@2}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you for your advice. May I ask what does the term 'k' represent?

Comment: @Corse I just defined your curve as `k + a*Exp[l*angle]`. So `k` and `l` are defined in terms of `xi` and `yi`.

Comment: pardon me for my ignorance, in which part of the code do you define the parameter 'a'? Is it in `ll[a_]`? Also, v1 and v2 are unit vectors of the sloping line?

Comment: I let `a` be unknown so I can change it at anytime. And `v1` and `v2` are just random vectors for the angle calculation.

Comment: i see, how do you change the value of `α`? i assume α is the angle B in my original illustration?

Comment: Alpha is calculated from the two vectors, and yes, alpha = B :)

Comment: Would i be right to say that the value of `a` is dependent on the angle `α`?

Comment: @Corse Not at all? You may change alpha, `a` will not get any bigger.

Comment: Oh no, I think I'm missing something. How would you change the value of `a`? via assignment?

Comment: @Corse `pts[a]` will work for `a < 5` if I remember correctly, after you need to use `fpts[a]` but it takes way longer due to the rearrangement of the points. So you can pick any value of `a != 0`.

Comment: ok so there isn't actually a numerical value assigned manually to `a` in this case?

Comment: No, everything in that case depends on `a`. I could have chosen an other parameter but here it's `a` :)

Comment: ah I see, let me take a closer look at your code =) really hope that i can understand it =X

Comment: @Corse There is nothing really complicated, the `angle` function is just the simplest way to calculate an angle between two vectors, the rest is just about what variable should I take for the function `r` start in `{x1, y1}` and end in `{x2, y2}`.

Comment: I'll have to put in more effort to understand mathematica's syntax. May i know what does the function ` pts[a_] ` do?

Comment: @Corse I'm basically just plotting the function with `Plot` between the appropriate bounds and pulling the graphical data (here points) from the `Plot`: `Cases[Plot[..., {...}], Line[x_] :> x, ∞]`. Meaning that in `Plot` I only take what's under the `Line` head, which is in this case the list of points. Then I `Join` the `{xi, yi}` points with the `Plot` points and I form a `Polygon` out of them. Since it's quiet a big set of point I sort them afterwards.

Comment: oh i see , could i check with you again , why is `k` and `l` necessary? can't quite get my head around this one

Comment: @Corse Maybe there are other ways, but my question was: *hey, how do I make sure that the function `r` will have the right shape and will cross the two points?* Saying `r = a*Exp[angle]` is like saying `r = x^2`; now if I ask you *I want x^2 to cross `{0 ,0}` and `{2, 3}`* you will try to change the model and see if an other one works. Thus you might try `a + b*x^2` and see if you can find `a` and `b` so both of them cross the points.

Comment: right, so you created a sort of 'general' equation for the log spiral! good thinking. by the way, how are `v1` and `v2` evaluated?

Comment: @Corse `v1` and `v2` are not evaluated at all, they are dummy variables in the `angle` function that are replaced by the desired vectors; in my case `{x2 - x1, y2 - y1}` and `{a, 0}` :)

Answer (score 3):

In this I have made $(x_2,y_2)$ the origin:

```
f[a_, t_] := a Exp[t]
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   ParametricPlot[{s f[a, t] Cos[t], s f[a, t] Sin[t]}, {t, angle, 
     0}, {s, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 0.1}}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, BoundaryStyle -> {Red, Thick}],
   Row[{"Area: ", Integrate[0.5 f[a, u]^2, {u, angle, 0}]}]
   }, Alignment -> Center]
 , {angle, -Pi/4, -Pi}, {a, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
Manipulate[Column[{ParametricPlot[s {f[a, t] Cos[t],
      -f[a, t] Sin[t]}, {t, 0, angle}, {s, 0, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 4}, {-10, 1}}, ImageSize -> 600, 
    BoundaryStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
    Epilog -> {Circle[{0, 0}, 1/2, {0, -angle}], 
      Text[Style[
        "(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(2\)]\),\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\))", 16], {0, 
        0}, {0, -1.5}], 
      Text[Style[
        "(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)+a,\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\
\), \(2\)]\))", 16], {1.4 a, 0}, {0, -1.5}], 
      Text[Style[
        "(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(1\)]\),\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(1\)]\))", 
        16], {a Exp[angle] Cos[angle], -a Exp[angle] Sin[angle]}, {0, 
        1.5}], Text[Style["B", 16], 
       0.8 {Cos[angle/2], -Sin[angle/2]}, {0, 0}]}], 
   Row[{"Area: ", Integrate[0.5 f[a, u]^2, {u, 0, angle}]}]}, 
  Alignment -> Center], {angle, Pi/4, Pi}, {a, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply! how did you define the coordinates of (x1,y1)?

Comment: @Corse I accept this may not be what you desired. (x1,y1) in the above (a exp(t)cos(t), a exp(t)sin(t)) where at t=0 is the horizontal point from origin

Comment: ah, but i believe this yields the same result as the proposed solution above. Let me try to understand the parametric manner of defining the area from your code