# Calculate area from `RegionPlot` directly

Tags: geometry, regions

I have a region plot, and I would like to calculate the area:

```
With[{b = 2, h = 2}, RegionPlot[
{(x)^2 + (y - b)^2 > h^2 + b^2 &&
(x)^2 + (y - b - h)^2 > h^2 + b^2 &&
(x - h)^2 + (y - 2 b - h)^2 > h^2 + b^2 &&
(x - h - b)^2 + (y - 2 b - h)^2 > h^2 + b^2 &&
(x - 2 h - b)^2 + (y - b - h)^2 > h^2 + b^2 &&
(x - 2 h - b)^2 + (y - b)^2 > h^2 + b^2 &&
(x - h - b)^2 + (y)^2 > h^2 + b^2 &&
(x - h)^2 + (y)^2 > h^2 + b^2}, {x, 0, 2 h + b}, {y, 0, 2 b + h}]]
```

I have tried defining it as an `ImplicitRegion` but `Area` evaluates to `Infinity`. I am sure I am doing something wrong that is very simple, but I can't see what.

Comment: Well, if you can extract the polygons, there's [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22543).

Comment: For approximate area: `Area @ DiscretizeGraphics @ g`. Where `g` is your graphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ImplicitRegion` seems to work fine:

```
ir = With[{b = 2, h = 2}, 
 ImplicitRegion[{(x)^2 + (y - b)^2 > 
   h^2 + b^2 && (x)^2 + (y - b - h)^2 > 
   h^2 + b^2 && (x - h)^2 + (y - 2 b - h)^2 > 
   h^2 + b^2 && (x - h - b)^2 + (y - 2 b - h)^2 > 
   h^2 + b^2 && (x - 2 h - b)^2 + (y - b - h)^2 > 
   h^2 + b^2 && (x - 2 h - b)^2 + (y - b)^2 > 
   h^2 + b^2 && (x - h - b)^2 + (y)^2 > 
   h^2 + b^2 && (x - h)^2 + (y)^2 > h^2 + b^2}, 
   {{x, 0, 2 h + b}, {y, 0, 2 b + h}}]];

FullSimplify[Area[ir]]

(* (8 Pi)/3 - 4 (-7 + 2 Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[7] + 4 ArcCos[3/4]) *)
```

which agrees with the approximate area based on the plot per [RunnyKine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5709/runnykine)'s comment

```
Area[DiscretizeGraphics[RegionPlot[ir]]]

(* 0.375737 *)
```

or the approximate area based on the discretized region

```
Area[DiscretizeRegion[ir]]

(* 0.374631 *)
```

The last value can be made more accurate by using a finer mesh.

```
Area[DiscretizeRegion[ir, PrecisionGoal -> 9]]

(* 0.374421 *)
```

Comment: ah - thank you! I was using `{x,y}` at the end insterad of `{{x, 0, 2 h + b}, {y, 0, 2 b + h}}` - I didn't realise you needed the extra curly brackets around it & wondered why `{x, 0, 2 h + b}, {y, 0, 2 b + h}` didn't work!!