# Unable to compute the area of a polygon

Tags: warning-messages, regions, geometry

I am having trouble computing the area of the following polygon. I have the following polygon:

```
polygon = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {2/10, 1}, {2/10, 8/10}, {4/10, 8/10}, {4/10, 6/10}, {1, 0}}]
```

The command

```
Region[polygon]
```

plots it just fine. I cannot hower compute its area using

```
RegionMeasure[polygon]
```

I get the following error

```
RegionMeasure::nmet: Unable to compute the measure of region Polygon[{{0,0},{0,1},{1/5,1},{1/5,4/5},{2/5,4/5},{2/5,3/5},{1,0}}]
```

It is not clear to me what causes this error.

EDIT: I need an exact result.

Comment: Hm. Runs without problems in version 12.0 for macos... But earlier versions of _Mathematica_ (like 10.x and 11.x) might have had problems with `Region`-related functions...

Comment: Runs without problems in  MMA version 12.0 for Windows 10 Home 64 bit.

Comment: I don't have an older version of MMA to try it with, but you might be able to try `Area[Region[polygon]]` or `RegionMeasure[Region[polygon]]`.

Comment: You can always use the [shoelace method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22587) for computing the area, of course.

Comment: Thanks, indeed my version 12.0 works. Unfortunately, my server runs 11.3 which would be great to use to speed up the computation. Both `Area[Region[polygon]]` and `RegionMeasure[Region[polygon]]` do not seem to work for me.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I will give the shoelace method a try.

Comment: You could always try `CloudEvaluate[Area[polygon]]` in your 11.3 session. I believe it will use the most recent version in the cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we first use [`DiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html), then it's no problem on version 10.1.

```
RegionMeasure@DiscretizeRegion@polygon
```

> 0.54

Comment: As far as I understand the DiscretizeRegion method I cannot be sure that it gives me an exact results, although it is the case here(represented as float). Unfortunately I need an exact results.