# Clickable Bounded Diagram

Tags: visualization

Suppose I make a `BoundedDiagram` via the following code

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
data2D = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 2}];
b1 = {{0, 0}, {11, 0}, {11, 11}, {0, 11}};
convexhull = ConvexHull[data2D];
delval = DelaunayTriangulation[data2D];
{vorvert, vorval} = VoronoiDiagram[data2D];
{dvert1, dval1} = BoundedDiagram[b1, data2D, delval, convexhull];
DiagramPlot[data2D, dvert1, dval1]
```

How would I go about making each region clickable, i.e. open some link that I associated with the data?

-- Edit:

I should note, all I really want is a to be able to click on regions of a Voronoi-Like diagram, it doesn't have to be done via BoundedDiagram, this is just my first attempt at doing that ... (and is basically straight from the documentation.)

Comment: That code does not work for me.

Comment: @Anon - Sorry, it's probably because I forgot to add the 'Needs' statement there; this question is within the `ComputationalGeometry` package.

Comment: Yes, that was it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will get you started:

```
nf = Nearest[data2D -> Automatic];
ClickPane[DiagramPlot[data2D, dvert1, dval1], (foo = nf[#]) &]
Dynamic@foo
```

Click on any region and `foo` is set equal to that region.  The [`ClickPane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClickPane.html) function `(foo = nf[#]) &` can be any function.  The [`NearestFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NearestFunction.html) given by `nf` returns the index of the point in `data2D` nearest the mouse click, whose coordinates are passed to the argument `#` of the `ClickPane` function.  That index is same as the index of the region.

A similar approach can be taken for any polygonal tiling, except `Nearest` works only for a Vononoi.  In other tilings, you have to write a function to find the polygon containing the mouse click.  [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/how-to-check-if-a-2d-point-is-in-a-polygon) can give you a start on that, if desired.

Comment: Thank's alot! (Extra letters to pass 15 character limit.)