# VoronoiMesh as a TogglerBar

Tags: list-manipulation, gui-construction, mesh, button

Is it possible to use a `VoronoiMesh` to define a `TogglerBar` or `SetterBar` type `Control`?

For example, I can customise the looks of a `TogglerBar`

```
Control[{{a, 0, ""},
  {1 -> Spacer[{.1, .1}], 4 -> Spacer[{.1, 20}], 
   7 -> Spacer[{.1, .1}], 2 -> Spacer[{20, .1}], 
   5 -> Spacer[{20, 20}], 8 -> Spacer[{20, .1}], 
   3 -> Spacer[{.1, .1}], 6 -> Spacer[{.1, 20}], 
   9 -> Spacer[{.1, .1}]},
  Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {3, 3}, ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

[image]

But this doesn't change the rectangle-shaped buttons and I don't think this is the way to go about if I want to define a `VoronoiMesh` with clickable and "toggleable" cells.

I want something like

[image]

where each cell is selected/unselected whenever I click it, adding/removing a correspondent number to a list, for example, in the case of a `TogglerBar`. I would like this to also work as a `SetterBar`.

Any ideas?

**Edit 1:** Thank you all for your answers. As a follow up, I'm now interested in developing a [`TogglerBar`-type object that allows users to hold and drag the mouse to select/deselect several cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212866/holding-and-dragging-mouse-to-select-multiple-buttons-cells). If you have time, please take a look at it, I'm a bit a clueless on how to do this, so any hint or idea is welcome.

**Edit 2:** Following Lukas Lang's answer below, I also tried to vary the grid size in `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[x,
 Control[{n, 2, 10, 1}],
 Control[{{x, 3, ""}, 
   MeshSetterBar[VoronoiMesh@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}]]}]]
```

However, this doesn't seem to behave as expected. Instead, I get

[image]

Any idea why, and how to fix this? I tried `Dynamic`, but didn't work.

**Edit 3:** As a third and (hopefully) final edit, thanks to Lukas Lang's answer, I was able to solve the original question. Now I just need to define several toggler-type meshes of the same shape. One naive attempt is simply

```
Manipulate[Null, Dynamic@Grid[{
    {Control[{n, 2, 10, 1}]},
    {Control[{{x, {}, ""}, 
       MeshTogglerBar[VoronoiMesh@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}]]}]},
    {Control[{{y, {}, ""}, 
       MeshTogglerBar[VoronoiMesh@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}]]}]}
    }]]
```

[image]

Which naturally doesn't yield meshes with the same shape, due to the randomness in defining the points. How can I solve this? I have tried to define the mesh outside, then I lose the dynamic update of the mesh-dependent control. I would like something like the following, where I'm able to independently update similarly shaped meshes

[image]

Comment: Some sort of `Manipulate` implementation?

Comment: [This](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PlayingWithStellationsOfTheIcosahedron/) has such a control. It seems to be written in V8, so no mesh.  The control does several things, so it's more complicated than you probably need.  It uses `ClickPane` to handle the mouse clicks and toggling.

Comment: Apparently I also wrote [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28396/4999), which someone just upvoted (thanks!).  You could use it to un/highlight the cell clicked I suppose.

Comment: It's somewhat frowned upon to keep updating an old Q&A with new questions, especially there is already an accepted answer. -- Anyway, all you have to do is pass the same mesh to MeshTogglerBar's first argument.

Comment: How so? If I fix `mesh=VoronoiMesh@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}]`, for example, the dynamic update dependent on `n` is lost. That is, the meshes aren't updated in real time. Or do you mean some other way?

Comment: I won't be updating this question anymore. I did it because all my extra questions were related to the main one.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want, but you could put `mesh=VoronoiMesh@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}]` in the `TrackingFunction` for `n`.  If you want the same mesh every time you come back to the same `n`, then you'll need to do something else, like define `mesh[n_] := mesh[n] = VoronoiMesh@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}]` or use `SeedRandom[]` or `meshTogglerBar[VoronoiMesh@Take[myBigListOfPoints, n]]` and so forth.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are implementations for a `MeshTogglerBar` and `MeshSetterBar` based on my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210552/how-to-dynamically-select-a-country-on-a-map-using-the-cursor) (code below). Both implementations use [`Mouseover`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mouseover.html) and [`EventHandler`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler.html) to handle detection of the polygon below the cursor for you. Compared to the [`NearestFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestFunction.html) approach, this is far more performant (since it is done by the front-end), it also works nicely for other types of meshes, where the cell below the cursor is not necessarily the one with the closest center.

### TogglerBar

[image: TogglerBar]

### SetterBar

[image: SetterBar]

## Code

```
MeshTogglerBar[mesh_] := iMeshTogglerBar[#, mesh] &
Dynamic[MeshTogglerBar[mesh_]] ^:= 
 Dynamic[iMeshTogglerBar[#, mesh] &]
MeshTogglerBar[Dynamic@var_, mesh_] := 
 iMeshTogglerBar[Dynamic@var, mesh]
iMeshTogglerBar[Dynamic@var_, mesh_] := Module[
  {prims = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]},
  With[
   {
    active = 
     Append[dragAction]@Table[Unique["active"], Length@prims],
    n = Length@prims
    },
   DynamicModule[
    active,
    Graphics[
     {
      FaceForm@White, EdgeForm@Blue,
      MapIndexed[
       With[
         {v = active[[#2[[1]]]]},
         EventHandler[
          Style[
           Annotation[#, ""],
           TagBoxOptions -> {
             BaseStyle -> FEPrivate`Which[
               FEPrivate`SameQ[v, True],
               {Lighter@Blue, EdgeForm@{Thick, Blue}},
               FrontEnd`CurrentValue@"MouseOver",
               LightBlue,
               True,
               {}
               ]
             }
           ],
          {
           "MouseEntered" :> FEPrivate`If[
             FEPrivate`And[
              FrontEnd`CurrentValue[{"MouseButtonTest", 1}],
              FEPrivate`UnsameQ[v, dragAction]
              ],
             FEPrivate`Set[v, dragAction];
             var[[#2[[1]]]] = dragAction
             ],
           {"MouseDown", 1} :> (
             FEPrivate`Set[dragAction, FEPrivate`UnsameQ[v, True]];
             FEPrivate`Set[v, dragAction];
             var[[#2[[1]]]] = dragAction
             )
           }
          ]
         ] &,
       prims
       ]
      },
     ImageSize -> Medium
     ],
    Initialization :> (
      If[ListQ@var,
       var = TrueQ /@ PadLeft[var, n, False],
       var = ConstantArray[False, n]
       ];
      MapThread[Set, {Most@active, var}]
      )
    ]
   ]
  ]

MeshSetterBar[mesh_] := iMeshSetterBar[#, mesh] &
Dynamic[MeshSetterBar[mesh_]] ^:= Dynamic[iMeshSetterBar[#, mesh] &]
MeshSetterBar[Dynamic@var_, mesh_] := iMeshSetterBar[Dynamic@var, mesh]
iMeshSetterBar[Dynamic@var_, mesh_] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {active},
  Graphics[
   {
    FaceForm@White,
    EdgeForm@Blue,
    MapIndexed[
     EventHandler[
       Style[
        Annotation[#, ""],
        TagBoxOptions -> {
          BaseStyle -> FEPrivate`Which[
            FEPrivate`SameQ[active, #2[[1]]],
            {Lighter@Blue, EdgeForm@{Thick, Blue}},
            FrontEnd`CurrentValue@"MouseOver",
            LightBlue,
            True,
            {}
            ]
          }
        ],
       {"MouseClicked" :> (
          FEPrivate`Set[active, #2[[1]]]; var = #2[[1]]
          )
        }
       ] &,
     MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]
     ]
    },
   ImageSize -> Medium
   ],
  Initialization :> (active =var)
  ]

SeedRandom[1]

mesh = VoronoiMesh@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}]

Dynamic@x

MeshSetterBar[Dynamic@x, mesh]

Dynamic@x

MeshTogglerBar[Dynamic@x, mesh]
```

### Notes

Some notes on the implementation (you can find some more in my answer linked above):

- Since everything is handled by the front-end, these controls will have excellent performance
- For the `MeshTogglerBar`, we have to generate a list of state variables (one per cell). This is because the front-end cannot manipulate lists, so each cell needs a separate variable
- The default values of the state variables are set in the [`Initialization`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Initialization.html) property of the [`DynamicModule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html) to ensure that the values are not prematurely inserted anywhere.
- The dynamic styling is done via `TagBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> {...}}`. This is done since we need to set the styles via an option for the front-end-only solution to work. The `Annotation[...]`/`TagBoxOptions` trick is to ensure that any type of primitive is styled, not only `Polygon`s.
- The controlled variables are kept separate from the `DynamicModule` variables used to store the state of the control. This ensures that the front-end ↔ kernel communication is kept to a minimum (i.e. only when a click has happened is the kernel variable updated).
- For the `MeshTogglerBar`, we trigger on both `"MouseEntered"` and `"MouseDown"` to enable dragging over many elements to toggle them. The state of the first element is stored in `dragAction`, to ensure that dragging sets all elements to the same state instead of toggling them back and forth
- The `iMeshTogglerBar`/`iMeshSetterBar` functions are there so the control can be easily used inside [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html):

  ```
  Manipulate[
    x,
    {{x, 3}, MeshSetterBar[mesh]}
   ]
  ```
- Similarly, the `Dynamic[MeshSetterBar[_]]`/`Dynamic[MeshTogglerBar[_]]` type definitions are to ensure that the controls work inside of `Manipulate` when the controls depend on other variables:

  ```
  Manipulate[x,
   {n, 2, 10, 1},
   {{x, 3, ""}, MeshSetterBar[VoronoiMesh@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}]]}
   ]
  ```

  The additional definition is necessary, since `Manipulate` wraps control specifications in `Dynamic` if any other manipulate variables occur in the specifications. This prevents `Manipulator` from seeing the `Function` expression, since it is not evaluated. The additional upvalue forces evaluation into something with an explicit `Function` in those cases.

Comment: Thank you! I just have one question: would it be possible to hold the mouse and select/unselect several cells just by dragging the mouse over them?

Comment: @samwolfe see the updated code - now you can hold the mouse button down and drag over other elements to set them all to the same state

Comment: That is great! I'm just getting a message in the beginning: "MapThread: incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2,1} and {2,2} of (...)". Once I drag the mouse over it, it's gone. Any idea how to fix this small issue?

Comment: @samwolfe Sorry, I missed a line when updating the code - should be fixed now

Comment: Thank you. I've just added a new edit section, because `Manipulate` doesn't seem to be working properly if I vary the mesh size with another `Control`. Can you please take a quick look?

Comment: @samwolfe I've updated the code to work in that case as well (see last point in the note section for details)

Comment: Using Toggler, whenever I select a cell, it automatically changes the mesh. I'm using `ConstantArray[False,10]` for the initial control value, though `ConstantArray[False,n]` should be what I wanted, I guess. Or simply `{}`. Can you check the Toggler case?

Comment: @samwolfe Sorry, I should have checked more carefully whether it really works. The updated version seems fine to me now (there was an issue causing the control to depend on `var`, which caused it to be updated every time `var` changed - now all that code is moved to `Initialization`, which removes the dependency). The initial value of the variable is automatically set - it tries to preserve the values from the previous setting and simply resizes the list of states to the correct length

Comment: That works well now! Thanks. To finish, I'm having just a small problem regarding defining two controls of this type that yield the same mesh shape. If you can, please take a look at Edit 3. In any case, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @samwolfe I think the simplest way to achieve what you're after is to safe the mesh into a temporary variable and use that for the second control: `Manipulate[{x, y}, {n, 2, 10, 1, ContinuousAction -> False}, {m, None}, {x, MeshTogglerBar[m = VoronoiMesh@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}]]},{y, MeshTogglerBar[m]}]`. The `{m, None}` part is to make `m` a variable local to the `Manipulate` (the `None` suppresses the generation of a control)

Answer (score 10):

```
ClearAll[togglerMesh]
togglerMesh = DynamicModule[{ m = #, ids = {},
     nF = Nearest[PropertyValue[{#, 2}, MeshCellCentroid] -> "Index"]}, 
    Dynamic@EventHandler[HighlightMesh[m, Thread[{2, Flatten@ids}]], 
      "MouseClicked" :> If[MemberQ[ids, #], ids = DeleteCases[ids, #], 
          AppendTo[ids, #]] &[If[MousePosition["Graphics"] === None, {}, 
        First@nF[MousePosition["Graphics"]]]]]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}];

vm = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
togglerMesh[vm]
```

[image]

```
dm = DelaunayMesh[pts, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
togglerMesh[dm]
```

[image]

Using a hexagonal mesh ([from this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212626/125)):

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = Flatten[Table[{3/2 i + RandomReal[.5], 
     Sqrt[3] j + Mod[i, 2] Sqrt[3]/2 + RandomReal[.5]}, {i, 7}, {j, 7}], 1];

hexmesh = DiscretizeGraphics @ Graphics @
   Select[Length[#[[1]]] == 6 &] @ MeshPrimitives[VoronoiMesh[pts], {2, "Interior"}];

togglerMesh[hexmesh]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! This more properly takes care of the "toggler" functionality.

Comment: Note that the `NearestFunction` will return the wrong cell in some cases for non-voronoi-type meshes. Try for example to select one of the narrow cells in your `DelaunyMesh` example with the cursor close to the corner

Answer (score 9):

```
SeedRandom[421]
points = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[points, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];

nf = Nearest[points -> Automatic];
primitives = MeshPrimitives[mesh, {2, All}];

Dynamic[
  ClickPane[
    HighlightMesh[mesh, {2, #}] & @@
      FirstPosition[
        primitives,
        SelectFirst[primitives, RegionMember[#, Extract[points, selected]] &]
      ],
    (selected = nf[#]) &
  ],
  Initialization :> (selected = {1})
]
```

[image: clicking on cell selects it]

@MichaelE2's answer to [Clickable Bounded Diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28396/27951) provided key inspiration; @PlatoManiac's code in their answer to [How to find adjacent polygons of a specific polygon in a VoronoiMesh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105216/27951) helped with the selection of the cell within which the mouse click is found

Comment: I'm getting an error message saying "Extract: position specification selected (...)". Any idea why?

Comment: @samwolfe It's an initialization problem when you first evaluate because `selected` has not yet been assigned any value. Just click any cell and it will work after that. Otherwise, add e.g. `Initialization :> (selected = {1})` as an option to `Dynamic`.