# How to determine whether a point is within a polygon in Mathematica 10

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry, version-10

In *Mathematica* 9, I was able to use the function `` Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ `` to determine whether a given point was within a polygon. How do I do this in *Mathematica* 10?

What I actually want to do is `RegionPlot` only the regions where my data has support. I used to define

```
data2 = Flatten[Table[{i, j, Sqrt[i^2 + j^2]}, {i, 1, 20}, {j, i/2, i, i/6}], 1];
supports = data2[[All, 1 ;; 2]];
<< ComputationalGeometry`
pol = supports[[ConvexHull[supports]]];
inPol = Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[pol, #] &;
```

and could then use

```
RegionPlot[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 10) && inPol[{x, y}], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

in order to plot a function (in the actual application it will be an interpolating function) only on the interesting region.

In Mathematica 10, `` Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ `` doesn't seem to exist anymore, or works differently.

Comment: That's because the function is in a different context in version 10: ``Graphics`PolygonUtils`InPolygonQ[]``. The context change was already noted in [this previous answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9417).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `ConvexHullMesh` to generate a geometric region to give as a plotting domain to `RegionPlot`.

Using your data:

```
data2 = Flatten[Table[{i, j, Sqrt[i^2 + j^2]}, {i, 1, 20}, {j, i/2, i, i/6}], 1];
supports = data2[[All, 1 ;; 2]];

RegionPlot[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 10, {x, y} ∈ ConvexHullMesh[supports]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

More in detail, here is the relationship between the original RegionPlot with no restrictions (in grey), the convex hull of the supports (green), and the resulting plot shown above (red):

```
Show[
 {
  ConvexHullMesh[supports, MeshCellStyle -> {{2} -> Opacity[0.5, Green]}],
  RegionPlot[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 10, {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> LightGray, BoundaryStyle -> Dashed],
  RegionPlot[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 10, {x, y} ∈ ConvexHullMesh[supports], PlotStyle -> Red]
 },
 Axes -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I like that I can actually define the plotting region as the supported region, saving me a lot of hassle with extrapolation going wrong.

Answer (score 15):

In v10 instead of `` Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ ``, you would use the more versatile `RegionMember`.

Rewriting your code to use it:

```
inPol = RegionMember[Polygon@pol, #] &

RegionPlot[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 10) && inPol[{x, y}], {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]