# How to determine if a point is within a concave 3D polyhedron?

Tags: graphics3d, finite-element-method, regions, mesh

Generally, if you have a 3D polyhedron and wanted to check if a point was within it, you would use something like a `ConvexHullMesh` to create a region, which you can then use `RegionMemberQ` to check if a point was within it.

But, this technique will not work for concave polyhedra. I have a programme which generates points to make a surface from. This works well, and I have posted the points & surface in a Pastebin.

```
points = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/190HQui1"];
polygon = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/d3MRBb8K"];

rmesh = Region[polygon];
Show[rmesh, points]
```

Now, how would I check if a point is within this shape?

[image: my shape]

I feel it is worth noting that `RegionDistance[polygon]`works, but only generates a 2-dimensional object - which works as expected - but we want to know if we are in the polyhedron. `ConvexHullMesh[polygon]` is a poor approximation
[image: convex hull].

There are these solutions to determine if a point is within a 2D polygon (even a convex one) ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99162/how-to-determine-whether-a-point-is-within-a-polygon-in-mathematica-10) [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/how-to-check-if-a-2d-point-is-in-a-polygon)). But they don't seem directly applicable to the 3D case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this:

```
polygon = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/d3MRBb8K"];
pts = Union @@ polygon[[1]];
nf = Nearest[pts -> "Index"];
R = BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, Polygon[DeleteDuplicates@*Flatten /@ Map[nf, polygon[[1]], {2}]]];
f = RegionMember[R]
```

Comment: This results in very strange behaviour with RegionDistance[R], e.g if you run
`rdf = RegionDistance[R];`
`DensityPlot[rdf[{x, y, 1.1}], {x, -10, 20}, {y, -10, 20}] `
You can see all the values which are smaller than 0 are considered in the volume!

Comment: That is indeed very odd. Maybe `BoundaryMeshRegion` does not orient the faces correctly, leading to some face normals that point inward instead of outward. I am not sure whether this is to be considered a bug. It seems that `BoundaryMeshRegion @*ToBoundaryMesh` is be the more robust way to create the `BoundaryMeshRegion`.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an alternative approach using [`SignedRegionDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SignedRegionDistance.html) that seems pretty fast, but I have not compared it to @Henrik Schumacher's answer.  It took about 5 seconds to test 100,000 points on my machine.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
points = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/190HQui1"];
polygon = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/d3MRBb8K"];
(* Convert into BoundaryMeshRegion *)
bmr = BoundaryMeshRegion[ToBoundaryMesh[Region[polygon]]];
(* create a SignedRegionDistance function *)
srdf = SignedRegionDistance[bmr];
(* create some random coodinates *)
crd = RandomReal[10, {100000, 3}];
(* If srdf is <0, then point is in region *)
inRegQ = PositionIndex[srdf[#] < 0 & /@ crd];
(* Show outside Points in Red and inside in Green *)
Show[Graphics3D[{{Red, Point[crd[[inRegQ[False]]]]}, {Green, 
    Point[crd[[inRegQ[True]]]]}}]]
(* Show points in region only *)
Show[RegionPlot3D[bmr, PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.25]], 
  Mesh -> None], Graphics3D[{{Green, Point[crd[[inRegQ[True]]]]}}]]
```

[image: Points in concave mesh]

## Timing Comparison

Since Henrik was so kind to speed up my code, I replicated some repeated timings on the various permutations.

```
(* Henrik's Answer *)
polygon = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/d3MRBb8K"];
pts = Union @@ polygon[[1]];
nf = Nearest[pts -> "Index"];
R = BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, 
   Polygon[DeleteDuplicates@*Flatten /@ Map[nf, polygon[[1]], {2}]]];
f = RegionMember[R];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(* Convert into BoundaryMeshRegion *)
bmr = BoundaryMeshRegion[ToBoundaryMesh[Region[polygon]]];
(* create SignedRegionDistance function based on bmr *)
srdfbmr = SignedRegionDistance[bmr];
(* create SignedRegionDistance function based on R*)
srdfr = SignedRegionDistance[R];
(* create some random coodinates *)
crd = RandomReal[10, {100000, 3}];
(* Henrik's Solution *)
{timeHS, inRegQ} = RepeatedTiming@PositionIndex[f[crd]];
(* Tim Laska's Original Solution *)
{timeTL, inRegQ} = 
  RepeatedTiming@PositionIndex[srdfbmr[#] < 0 & /@ crd];
(* Tim Laska's With Henrik's UnitStep Suggestion *)
{timeHSSug, inRegQ} = 
  RepeatedTiming@
   PositionIndex[{True, False}[[UnitStep[srdfbmr[crd]] + 1]]];
(* Tim Laska's With Henrik's Polygon *)
{timeTLR, inRegQ} = 
  RepeatedTiming@PositionIndex[srdfr[#] < 0 & /@ crd];
(* Tim Laska's With Henrik's UnitStep Suggestion and His Polygon *)
{timeHSSugPoly, inRegQ} = 
  RepeatedTiming@
   PositionIndex[{True, False}[[UnitStep[srdfr[crd]] + 1]]];
data = {{"Henrik's Answer", timeHS}, {"Tim's Original", 
    timeTL}, {"Tim's with Henrik's UnitStep", 
    timeHSSug}, {"Tim's with Henrik's Poly", 
    timeTLR}, {"Tim's with Henrik's Poly and UnitStep", 
    timeHSSugPoly}};
data = SortBy[data, Last];
Text@Grid[Prepend[data, {"Method", "Time(s)"}], 
  Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9], {White, 
      Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}}, 
  Dividers -> {{Darker[Gray, .6], {Lighter[Gray, .5]}, 
     Darker[Gray, .6]}, {Darker[Gray, .6], Darker[Gray, .6], {False}, 
     Darker[Gray, .6]}}, Alignment -> {{Left, Right, {Left}}}, 
  ItemSize -> {{20, 5}}, Frame -> Darker[Gray, .6], ItemStyle -> 14, 
  Spacings -> {Automatic, .8}]
```

[image: Timing Comparison]

On my machine, Henrik's UnitStep suggestion boosted performance about 3x.  The performance of RegionMember and SignedRegionDistance are similar with Henrik's suggestion.

Comment: `Map`ping `srdf` makes it quite slow. `{True, False}[[UnitStep[srdf[crd]] + 1]]` is almost 4 times faster; and so is `RegionMember`. I don't know what `ToBoundaryMesh` does exactly, but for some reason, using the region `R`as created by me instead of `bmr` seems to be slightly faster (and leads to the same results).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you very much for your insight.  I will try to incorporate your suggestions soon.  I suspect the triangle count changes as ToBoundaryMesh will try to make the polygons isotropic.

Comment: "will try to make the polygons isotropic."Ah right, I get it. This is a good thing for many tasks, but for this one, it is just not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a method that takes around 2-2.5 times longer than the one from @TimLaska. It has the advantage that it can perhaps be made considerably faster using `Compile`. It is code [from here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116160/determine-whether-points-lie-within-a-cow) that I adjusted slightly for the problem at hand.

The main idea is to find boundary triangles that a ray from the outside to the given point can intersect. We count these; odd means point is inside. I used a random transformation to avoid zero denominators that can arise with data that is too well "aligned" with one or more coordinate axes.

```
points0 = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/190HQui1"];
pgon0 = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/d3MRBb8K"];

SeedRandom[1234];
randpt = RandomReal[1, 3];
translate = TranslationTransform[randpt];
randdir = RandomReal[1, 3];
theta = RandomReal[Pi];
rotate = RotationTransform[theta, randdir];
transform = Composition[rotate, translate];

rmesh0 = Region[pgon0];

makeTriangles[tri : {aa_, bb_, cc_}] := {tri}
makeTriangles[{aa_, bb_, cc_, dd__}] := 
 Join[{{aa, bb, cc}}, makeTriangles[{aa, cc, dd}]]

triangles = 
  Map[transform, 
   Flatten[Map[makeTriangles, rmesh0[[1, 1]]], 1], {2}];
verts = Map[transform, points0[[All, 1, 1]]];

flats = Map[Most, triangles, {2}];
pts = verts;
xcoords = pts[[All, 1]];
ycoords = pts[[All, 2]];
zcoords = pts[[All, 3]];
xmin = Min[xcoords];
ymin = Min[ycoords];
xmax = Max[xcoords];
ymax = Max[ycoords];
zmin = Min[zcoords];
zmax = Max[zcoords];

n = 100;
mult = 1.03;
xspan = xmax - xmin;
yspan = ymax - ymin;
dx = mult*xspan/n;
dy = mult*yspan/n;
midx = (xmax + xmin)/2;
midy = (ymax + ymin)/2;
xlo = midx - mult*xspan/2;
ylo = midy - mult*yspan/2;

edges[{a_, b_, c_}] := {{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, a}}

vertexBox[{x1_, y1_}, {xb_, yb_, dx_, dy_}] := {Ceiling[(x1 - xb)/dx],
   Ceiling[(y1 - yb)/dy]}

segmentBoxes[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}, {xb_, yb_, dx_, dy_}] := 
 Module[{xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, xlo, xhi, ylo, yhi, xtable, ytable, 
   xval, yval, index}, xmin = Min[x1, x2];
  xmax = Max[x1, x2];
  ymin = Min[y1, y2];
  ymax = Max[y1, y2];
  xlo = Ceiling[(xmin - xb)/dx];
  ylo = Ceiling[(ymin - yb)/dy];
  xhi = Ceiling[(xmax - xb)/dx];
  yhi = Ceiling[(ymax - yb)/dy];
  xtable = Flatten[Table[xval = xb + j*dx;
     yval = (((-x2)*y1 + xval*y1 + x1*y2 - xval*y2))/(x1 - x2);
     index = Ceiling[(yval - yb)/dy];
     {{j, index}, {j + 1, index}}, {j, xlo, xhi - 1}], 1];
  ytable = Flatten[Table[yval = yb + j*dy;
     xval = (((-y2)*x1 + yval*x1 + y1*x2 - yval*x2))/(y1 - y2);
     index = Ceiling[(xval - xb)/dx];
     {{index, j}, {index, j + 1}}, {j, ylo, yhi - 1}], 1];
  Union[Join[xtable, ytable]]]

pointInsideTriangle[
  p : {x_, y_}, {{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, {x3_, y3_}}] := 
 With[{l1 = -((x1*y - x3*y - x*y1 + x3*y1 + x*y3 - x1*y3)/(x2*y1 - 
         x3*y1 - x1*y2 + x3*y2 + x1*y3 - x2*y3)), 
   l2 = -(((-x1)*y + x2*y + x*y1 - x2*y1 - x*y2 + x1*y2)/(x2*y1 - 
         x3*y1 - x1*y2 + x3*y2 + x1*y3 - x2*y3))}, 
  Min[x1, x2, x3] <= x <= Max[x1, x2, x3] && 
   Min[y1, y2, y3] <= y <= Max[y1, y2, y3] && 0 <= l1 <= 1 && 
   0 <= l2 <= 1 && l1 + l2 <= 1]

faceBoxes[
  t : {{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, {x3_, y3_}}, {xb_, yb_, dx_, dy_}] := 
 Catch[Module[{xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, xlo, xhi, ylo, yhi, xval, yval,
     res}, xmin = Min[x1, x2, x3];
   xmax = Max[x1, x2, x3];
   ymin = Min[y1, y2, y3];
   ymax = Max[y1, y2, y3];
   If[xmax - xmin < dx || ymax - ymin < dy, Throw[{}]];
   xlo = Ceiling[(xmin - xb)/dx];
   ylo = Ceiling[(ymin - yb)/dy];
   xhi = Ceiling[(xmax - xb)/dx];
   yhi = Ceiling[(ymax - yb)/dy];
   res = Table[xval = xb + j*dx;
     yval = yb + k*dy;
     If[pointInsideTriangle[{xval, yval}, 
       t], {{j, k}, {j + 1, k}, {j, k + 1}, {j + 1, k + 1}}, {}], {j, 
      xlo, xhi - 1}, {k, ylo, yhi - 1}];
   res = res /. {} :> Sequence[];
   Flatten[res, 2]]]

gridBoxes[pts : {a_, b_, c_}, {xb_, yb_, dx_, dy_}] := 
 Union[Join[Map[vertexBox[#, {xb, yb, dx, dy}] &, pts], 
   Flatten[Map[segmentBoxes[#, {xb, yb, dx, dy}] &, edges[pts]], 1], 
   faceBoxes[pts, {xb, yb, dx, dy}]]]
```

Creating the main structure takes a bit of up-front time.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 gbox = DeleteCases[
   Map[gridBoxes[#, {xlo, ylo, dx, dy}] &, 
    flats], {a_, b_} /; (a > n || b > n), 2];
 grid = ConstantArray[{}, {n, n}];
 Do[Map[AppendTo[grid[[Sequence @@ #]], j] &, gbox[[j]]], {j, 
   Length[gbox]}];]

(* Out[2893]= {1.47625, Null} *)

planeTriangleParams[
  p : {x_, y_}, {p1 : {x1_, y1_}, p2 : {x2_, y2_}, p3 : {x3_, y3_}}] :=
  With[{den = 
    x2*y1 - x3*y1 - x1*y2 + x3*y2 + x1*y3 - 
     x2*y3}, {-((x1*y - x3*y - x*y1 + x3*y1 + x*y3 - x1*y3)/
      den), -(((-x1)*y + x2*y + x*y1 - x2*y1 - x*y2 + x1*y2)/den)}]

getTriangles[p : {x_, y_}] := 
 Module[{ix, iy, triangs, params, res}, {ix, iy} = 
   vertexBox[p, {xlo, ylo, dx, dy}];
  triangs = grid[[ix, iy]];
  params = Map[planeTriangleParams[p, flats[[#]]] &, triangs];
  res = Thread[{triangs, params}];
  Select[res, 
   0 <= #[[2, 1]] <= 1 && 
     0 <= #[[2, 2]] <= 1 && #[[2, 1]] + #[[2, 2]] <= 1.0000001 &]]

countAbove[p : {x_, y_, z_}] := 
 Module[{triangs = getTriangles[Most[p]], threeDtriangs, lambdas, 
   zcoords, zvals}, threeDtriangs = triangles[[triangs[[All, 1]]]];
  lambdas = triangs[[All, 2]];
  zcoords = threeDtriangs[[All, All, 3]];
  zvals = 
   Table[zcoords[[j, 1]] + 
     lambdas[[j, 1]]*(zcoords[[j, 2]] - zcoords[[j, 1]]) + 
     lambdas[[j, 2]]*(zcoords[[j, 3]] - zcoords[[j, 1]]), {j, 
     Length[zcoords]}];
  If[OddQ[Length[triangs]] && OddQ[Length[Select[zvals, z > # &]]], 
   Print[{p, triangs, Length[Select[zvals, z > # &]]}]];
  Length[Select[zvals, z > # &]]]

isInside[{x_, y_, 
    z_}] /; ! ((xmin <= x <= xmax) && (ymin <= y <= ymax) && (zmin <= 
       z <= zmax)) := False
isInside[p : {x_, y_, z_}] := OddQ[countAbove[p]]
```

Running it takes 8.8 seconds.

```
SeedRandom[12345];
crd = Map[transform, RandomReal[10, {100000, 3}]];
AbsoluteTiming[inRegQ = Map[isInside, crd];]

(* Out[2906]= {8.83544, Null} *)
```

The code from Tim Laska took around 4.3 seconds on this machine for the same point set. I suspect that could be attained by a `Compile`d version of the above.