# Is there a simple strategy to determine whether a point is inside a boundary?

Tags: computational-geometry

For a ellipse $E(\theta)$, which owns the parametric equation as follows:

$\begin{cases}
 x = a \sin\theta + b \cos\theta + c  \\
 y = d \sin\theta + e \cos\theta + f \\
\end{cases}$

Now, I have a point $P=\{x_p,y_p\}$, to know the relationship between $E(\theta)$ and $P=\{x_p,y_p\}$, I using this method:

$$
\begin{cases}
\sin \theta =\frac{(c-x_p)e+b(y_p-f)}{b d-a e}\\
\cos \theta =\frac{(-c+x_p)d+a(f-y_p)}{b d-a e}
\end{cases} 
$$

compute $m=\sin^2 \theta+\cos^2 \theta$

- if $m=1$, the point $P$ on the ellipse $E(\theta)$
- if $m>1$, the point $P$ outside the ellipse $E(\theta)$
- if $m<1$, the point $P$ inside the ellipse $E(\theta)$

However, for the compound curve, for example

- ellipse segment $E_1(\theta) \qquad \theta \in [0, 2.4798],[5.8629, 2 \pi]$
- ellipse segment $E_2(\theta) \qquad \theta \in [3.1275, 6.1325]$
- line segment $L(E_1(2.4798),E_2(3.1275))$

---

```
mat1 = {{0., -5., 0}, {-5.2203, 0., 1.7945}}; 
mat2 = {{-0.8583, -4.9384, 0.1765}, {-5.4189, 0.7822, 2.3088}};
θ1 = 2.4798;
θ2 = 3.1275;
Show[
  {ParametricPlot[
     mat1.{Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 1}, {θ, 0, 2.4798}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   ParametricPlot[
     mat1.{Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 1}, {θ, 5.8629, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red],
   ParametricPlot[
     mat2.{Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 1}, {θ, 3.1275, 6.1325}],
   Graphics[
     {Line[{mat1.{Sin[θ1], Cos[θ1], 1}, mat2.{Sin[θ2], Cos[θ2], 1}}]}]}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now, I have two points $P_1,P_2$, whose coordinate are `{{-4.50722, 0.455707}, {5.2748, 2.68502}}`,respectively.So I would like to know is there a **simple** method to determine whether $P$ **inside** the boundary?

[image]

Comment: Can't you use `RegionMember`?

Comment: if performance is important, the *fastest* and most precise approach I suspect will be to use `FindRoot` to find where/if each segment intersects a line from `P` to `(Infinity,Py)`.  Then just count the roots, `odd->inside`

Comment: @george2079 Could you give me a explanation about  `(Infinity,Py)`? Thanks:)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way you can do this is to first discretize the graphics, then turn it into a region with an interior using `DelaunayMesh`, and finally using `RegionMember`:

```
mat1 = {{0., -5., 0}, {-5.2203, 0., 1.7945}}; 
mat2 = {{-0.8583, -4.9384, 0.1765}, {-5.4189, 0.7822, 2.3088}};
θ1 = 2.4798;
θ2 = 3.1275;
gr=
 Show[
  {ParametricPlot[
     mat1.{Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 1}, {θ, 0, 2.4798}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   ParametricPlot[
     mat1.{Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 1}, {θ, 5.8629, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red],
   ParametricPlot[
     mat2.{Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 1}, {θ, 3.1275, 6.1325}],
   Graphics[
     {Line[{mat1.{Sin[θ1], Cos[θ1], 1}, mat2.{Sin[θ2], Cos[θ2], 1}}]}]}, 
  PlotRange -> All];
```

Now we turn the graphics into a region:

```
dg = DelaunayMesh@MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeGraphics@gr;
```

And we can now determine that `{0,3}` is inside this region:

```
RegionMember[dg, {0., 3.}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Note that you can get better performance by creating a `RegionMemberFunction` and applying it directly to a list of points (it's `Listable`).

```
rf = RegionMember[dg]; (* create RegionMemberFunction *)
rf[{{0., 3.}, {0., 2.}, {5., 0.}, {0., 8.}, {1., 1.}}] (* apply the function *)
```

> `{True, True, False, False, True}`

Comment: Apart from  `DelaunayMesh[]` and `RegionMember[]`(I think `DelaunayMesh[]` is time-consuming ). I would like to know is there other simple method to do this problem?

Comment: @ShutaoTANG, you can also use `ConvexHullMesh` in place of `DelaunayMesh`.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Another approach is to use `SignedRegionDistance` in place of `RegionMember` and if the result is negative it means the point is inside the region and outside otherwise.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 10):

I am going to use `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`PointWindingNumber `` from [R.M's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9417/8070) to [How to check if a 2D point is in a polygon?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/how-to-check-if-a-2d-point-is-in-a-polygon). In M10 you can use `RegionMember`.

The idea is to convert your region into a polygon and then test if the point is inside or not.

```
mat1 = {{0., -5., 0}, {-5.2203, 0., 1.7945}}; 
mat2 = {{-0.8583, -4.9384, 0.1765}, {-5.4189, 0.7822, 2.3088}};

q1 = 2.4798; q2 = 3.1275;
dq = 0.1; (*use smaller value for better precession*)
seg1 = Table[mat1.{Sin[q], Cos[q], 1}, {q, 0, 2.4798, dq}];
seg2 = Table[mat1.{Sin[q], Cos[q], 1}, {q, 5.8629, 2 Pi, dq}];
seg3 = Table[mat2.{Sin[q], Cos[q], 1}, {q, 3.1275, 6.1325, dq}];
seg4 = {mat1.{Sin[q1], Cos[q1], 1}, mat2.{Sin[q2], Cos[q2], 1}};
path = Join[seg1, seg2, seg3, seg4];

(*Make a continuous path from all the points*)
spath = FindCurvePath[path]//First; 
boundary = path[[#]] & /@ spath;

inPolyQ[poly_, pt_] := Graphics`PolygonUtils`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] =!= 0


Manipulate[Graphics[Line[boundary], 
 PlotLabel -> Text[Style[StringForm["Point`` is ``", p, 
  If[inPolyQ[boundary, p], "Inside ", "Outside"]], Bold, Italic]]],
 {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

**For Mathematica9**

For MMA9 you have to use `` Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] `` in place of `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] ``.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB for the edit. You left a � after the final bracket. So I am taking the advantage ;)

Comment: sorry about that! That's what I get for doing edits on my silly tablet! :-) I've got to look into this `PointWindingNumber` thing. It sounds very cool! Thanks for digging it out.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a bit of an overkill. Imagine the points on the boundary and the points you input as electric charges:

```
mat1 = {{0., -5., 0}, {-5.2203, 0., 1.7945}}; 
mat2 = {{-0.8583, -4.9384, 0.1765}, {-5.4189, 0.7822, 2.3088}};
θ1 = 2.4798;
θ2 = 3.1275;
g=Show[
  {ParametricPlot[
     mat1.{Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 1}, {θ, 0, 2.4798}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   ParametricPlot[
     mat1.{Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 1}, {θ, 5.8629, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red],
   ParametricPlot[
     mat2.{Sin[θ], Cos[θ], 1}, {θ, 3.1275, 6.1325}, PlotStyle -> Red],
   Graphics[
     {Thick, Red, Line[{mat1.{Sin[θ1], Cos[θ1], 1}, mat2.{Sin[θ2], Cos[θ2], 1}}]}]}, 
  PlotRange -> All];

step[form_] := 
 Function[# - 
    10^-4 Sum[
      Normalize[ext[[i]] - #]/Norm[ext[[i]] - #]^2, {i, 
       Length@ext}]] /@ form
relax[object_, t_] := First@{
   ext = RandomPoint[DiscretizeGraphics@g, 10^3];
   fin = NestList[step, object, t]; 
   Print@ListAnimate[
     Function@Show[g, #, Axes -> False] /@ 
      Function@ListPlot[#, PlotStyle -> Gray] /@ fin];
   Table[{Part[First@fin, i], 
      If[EuclideanDistance[Part[Last@fin, i], Mean@ext] - 
         EuclideanDistance[Part[First@fin, i], Mean@ext] < 0, 
       Text["Inside"], Text["Outside"]]}, {i, Length@First@fin}
     ] // MatrixForm
   }
```

**Usage**

Note that increasing `t` yields more accurate results.

```
relax[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {5, 6}}, 100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

the direct approach:

```
mat1 = {{0., -5., 0}, {-5.2203, 0., 1.7945}};
mat2 = {{-0.8583, -4.9384, 0.1765}, {-5.4189, 0.7822, 2.3088}};
\[Theta]1 = 2.4798;
\[Theta]2 = 3.1275;
f[1, t_] := mat1.{Sin[t], Cos[t], 1};
f[2, t_] := mat1.{Sin[t], Cos[t], 1};
f[3, t_] := mat2.{Sin[t], Cos[t], 1};
f[4, t_] := 
            t mat1.{Sin[\[Theta]1], Cos[\[Theta]1], 1} +  
      (1 - t) mat2.{Sin[\[Theta]2], Cos[\[Theta]2], 1};
f[1, "range"] = Sequence @@ {0, \[Theta]1};
f[2, "range"] = Sequence @@ {5.8629, 2 Pi};
f[3, "range"] = Sequence @@ {\[Theta]2, 6.1325};
f[4, "range"] = Sequence @@ {0, 1};

p = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {2}]
Show[{Graphics@{PointSize[.025], Point[p], Arrow[{p, p + {10, 0}}]},
  Table[ParametricPlot[f[k, t], Evaluate@{t, f[k, "range"]}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red], {k, 4}]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

count the crossings, if odd we are inside.

```
OddQ@Total@Table[ Length[t /. Quiet@NSolve[f[k, t][[2]] == #[[2]] && 
          Less @@ Riffle[{f[k, "range"]}, t] && 
          f[k, t][[1]] > #[[1]] , t]] , {k, 4}] &@p
```

> True

process a bunch of points:

```
p = RandomReal[{-8, 8}, {20, 2}];
pin = Select[p, 
   OddQ@Total@Table[ Length[t /. Quiet@NSolve[f[k, t][[2]] == #[[2]] && 
            Less @@ Riffle[{f[k, "range"]}, t] && 
            f[k, t][[1]] > #[[1]] , t]] , {k, 4}] &];
Show[{Graphics@{PointSize[.025], Point[p], Red, PointSize[.02], 
    Point[pin]},
  Table[ParametricPlot[f[k, t], Evaluate@{t, f[k, "range"]}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red], {k, 4}]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

If you have functions that `NSolve` can't handle you can use other methods such as `FindRoot`, but you need a scheme to find all the roots, and then you might loose the performance advantage over other methods.

Also to make this robust you need to deal with cases where your projected line exactly hits a junction between piecewise curves. (do a `Union` on the roots for example )

Answer (score 1):

```
    gra = Show[{ParametricPlot[
         mat1.{Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]], 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2.4798}, 
         PlotStyle -> Red], 
        ParametricPlot[
         mat1.{Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]], 1}, {\[Theta], 5.8629, 2 Pi},
          PlotStyle -> Red], 
        ParametricPlot[
         mat2.{Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]], 1}, {\[Theta], 3.1275, 
          6.1325}], 
        Graphics[{Line[{mat1.{Sin[\[Theta]1], Cos[\[Theta]1], 1}, 
            mat2.{Sin[\[Theta]2], Cos[\[Theta]2], 1}}]}]}, 
       PlotRange -> All];
    RegionMember[
 ConvexHullMesh@MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeGraphics@gra, {0, 3}]
```

> True

Comment: Obviously, `{0,3}` is inside the boundary. Why your answer is `False`?:)

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Well just misunderstand your English.I thought you jedge whether or not in the boundry but inside.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you would do that in Mathematica, but the simplest way to check if a point is inside a closed shape, is to draw a line through the point.
Then count intersections with the border of the shape from the point going outwards.
If the number is odd, it's inside.

Comment: This is more of a comment than answer. If you would like to expand on it and write an actual answer, feel free! Otherwise, please post this is a comment.

Comment: Also, quoting from @george2079's comment from 5 hours ago: "Then just count the roots, odd->inside." You might want to turn this into code if you can.