# Selecting points inside a closed curve

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, geometry

Let's create a rather dense grid of initial conditions

```
xlim = 4;
ds = 0.05;
data = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -xlim, xlim, ds}, {j, -xlim, xlim, ds}], 1];
nic = Length[data]
L0 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.001]}];
```

Then we define a closed two-dimensional curve

```
C0 = ContourPlot[x^2/4 + y^2/9 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
     PlotPoints -> 100, ContourStyle -> {Black, Thick}];
d0 = C0[[1, 1]];
S0 = ListPlot[d0, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}, Joined -> True];
```

Here I would like to clarify that in my real case scenario we **do not** know the analytical expression of the closed curve. We only have a list of points such as `d0`.

```
P0 = Show[{L0, S0}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Now I would like to create a new list `data2` which will contain all the points of the initial `data` that are inside the closed curve.

I am using version 9.0 in 32bit Win XP.

Any suggestions?

**NOTE:** This question [point-in a polygon test](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/how-to-check-if-a-2d-point-is-in-a-polygon) looks very similar. However in my case performance over a large number of points is important.

Comment: You could use a [point-in-polygon test](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9405).

Comment: @J.M.  That looks like a duplicate to me; do you disagree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not exactly a duplicate! I want to filter a large amount of points and see which of them are inside the curve.

Comment: I think so, @Mr. Wizard, but hesitated to close outright without acknowledgment from the OP.

Comment: Your "curve" is actually a polygon, so the solutions in the linked thread apply, Vaggelis. Did you even try any of the solutions?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Please edit your question to include a link to [(9405)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9405/121), and emphasize that performance over a large number of points is important.

Comment: If you have V10, you can use things like `data2 = Select[data, RegionMember[DelaunayMesh[d0]]]`, (but looks like this is very inefficient)

Comment: @happyfish The OP specifically says that he is using version 9.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I saw that. But I think as a general question, easy solutions in V10 would help future visitors.

Comment: @happyfish Okay.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z It would appear that of the existing answers Daniel's is likely most optimized for speed: [(9489)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9489/121) -- have you tried that yet?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The answer looks rather complicated and I really don't know how to fit it to my case. I was hoping for a quick a dirty solution.

Comment: What does ``?*`*InPolygonQ`` return for you?

Comment: @J.M. If I evaluate ``?*`*InPolygonQ`` I get the following three lines: ``Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ
Attributes[Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ]={Protected}
Options[Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ]={Method->Automatic}``

Comment: Then yes, you can use that function; probably use it along with `Select[]` on all your points. Why not test that first? If it's too slow, then we can worry…

Comment: @J.M. Now you lost me! How exactly can I use it? Perhaps suggesting a quick answer.

Comment: The question you linked has 11 answers - were *all* of them too slow? At least one answer includes a timing measurement that (I think) means it can process 1 million points per second. How many points do you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you produce your data

```
xlim = 4;
ds = 0.25;
data = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -xlim, xlim, ds}, {j, -xlim, xlim, ds}], 1];
nic = Length[data]
```

Then you make your `contour` from arbitrary points and get the polygon out of it

```
pts = RandomReal[{2, 3}] {Cos[#], Sin[#]} & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/20];
contour = ListLinePlot[pts, AspectRatio -> 1,  
                       PlotRange -> {{-xlim, xlim}, {-xlim, xlim}}]
poly = Cases[Normal@contour, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity];
```

[image]

Actually here `poly` is `pts`. This method comes handy if you want to get the points from an analytical expression. In worst case if your data is not ordered, use

```
poly = Sort[pts, ArcTan @@ #1 > ArcTan @@ #2 &];
```

And then use `RegionMember` to find the points.

```
data2 = Select[data, RegionMember[Polygon[poly], #] &];

ListPlot[{data, data2}, 
PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Medium], PointSize[Large]}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

**For Mathematica9**

For MMA9 you have to use `` Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber `` which I first found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9417/8070). In that case,

```
inPolyQ[poly_, pt_] := Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] =!= 0
data2 = Select[data, inPolyQ[poly, #] &];

ListPlot[{data, data2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Medium], PointSize[Large]}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

For details you can check [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111123/8070) to [Is there a simple strategy to determine whether a point is inside a boundary?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111114/is-there-a-simple-strategy-to-determine-whether-a-point-is-inside-a-boundary/111123#111123)

Comment: This works only when the curve has a known analytical expression. In my real case, the curve is given only as a set of points.

Comment: Just make a close contour anyway. Hold on I am going to give an example with arbitrary point.

Comment: `RegionMember` is introduced in V10, may need to replace it to run on OP's computer

Comment: @happyfish Sorry, I noticed that. Unfortunately now I don't have M9 in my hand, so I just describe the method for M9 without an example.

Comment: In v9 when I evaluate `data2 = Select[data, inPolyQ[poly, #] &];` I get exactly the same points as in `data`.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, My bad, it would be ``Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber``. I modified my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Now I get the following error message: Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber::invpoly: -- Message text not found -- (Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber[{{{2.88617,0.},{2.8451,0.45062},{2.42173,0.786868},<<35>>,{2.20662,-0.716976},{2.50074,-0.396078},{2.99428,0.}}},{-4.,-4.}])

Comment: Check if your `poly` is a `{n,2}` array (`Dimensions[poly]`). Looks like there is an extra `{}`. In that case just use `poly[[1]]` in `inPolyQ`.

Comment: Many thanks! Your solution in v9 works fine. I borrowed a newer laptop with v10 installed and your second solution also works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, at least, what you seek can be achieved by evaluating the function defining the contour at each of your test points

```
data1 = Select[data, Function[{xy}, xy[[1]]^2/4 + xy[[2]]^2/9 < 1]];
L1 = ListPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.001]}];
P1 = Show[{L1, S0}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: No, this is not what I want. This is just a simple example. In my real case the analytical expression of the closed curve is unknown. I have only a set of $(x_0,y_0)$ points which define a closed curve.