# Predicting the initial conditions of orbits inside a closed curve

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting, interpolation

I have a [data file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/cf1f0yz0jmdu1da/lyap_4d.dat) containing the four orbital element $(x,y,p_x,p_y)$ of a two-dimensional closed loop orbit. Note that the exact implicit equation of the orbit is not known.

The plot of the 2D orbit on the $(x,y)$ plane

```
data = Import["lyap_4d.dat", "Table"];
d00 = data[[All, {1, 2}]];

C0 = ListLinePlot[d00, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All, 
     Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]
```

[image]

Now let's define a rectangular grid of initial conditions around this orbit

```
data = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0.785, 1.135, 0.005}, 
       {j, -0.45, 0.45, 0.005}], 1];
nic = Length[data]
L0 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.001]}];
plot1 = Show[{L0, C0}]
```

[image]

Finally, we determine which of the initial conditions are inside the orbit using the code provided [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118791/selecting-points-inside-a-closed-curve)

```
poly = Cases[Normal@C0, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity];
inPolyQ[poly_, pt_] := Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] =!= 0
data2 = Select[data, inPolyQ[poly[[1]], #] &];
nic2 = Length[data2]
L1 = ListPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.001]}];
plot2 = Show[{L1, C0}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

The list `data2` contains all the $(x_0,y_0)$ initial conditions inside the orbit.

My question is the following: For the boundary orbit the $p_x$ and $p_y$ values are known. How can I use these values so as to predict in a way the $(p_{x0},p_{y0})$ of the orbits with initial conditions inside the orbit? In other words, how can I interpolate the $p_x$ and $p_y$ of the orbit by taking into account the values of the boundary?

I use version 9.0 of Mathematica in Win XP SP3.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an interpolating function for both `px` and `py` from the data you have:

```
data = Import["Downloads/lyap_4d.dat", "Table"];
d00 = data[[All, {1, 2}]];
pyfunc = Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #4} & @@@ data, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
pxfunc = Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@ data, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

That answers the question of how to get the interpolated values inside the curve, but how can they be plotted?

In versions later than 10.0 you can make a plot of the momenta inside the curve very easily,

```
DensityPlot[pxfunc[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ConvexHullMesh[d00]]
DensityPlot[pyfunc[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ConvexHullMesh[d00]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But in version 9 you have to do it the hard way (borrowing from the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9408/9490) for the `RegionFunction`),

```
winding[poly_, pt_] := 
  Round[(Total@
       Mod[(# - RotateRight[#]) &@(ArcTan @@ (pt - #) & /@ poly), 
        2 Pi, -Pi]/2/Pi)];
testpoint[poly_, pt_] := 
  Round[(Total@
        Mod[(# - RotateRight[#]) &@(ArcTan @@ (pt - #) & /@ poly), 
         2 Pi, -Pi]/2/Pi)] != 0;

DensityPlot[
 pxfunc[x, y], {x, Min@d00[[All, 1]], Max@d00[[All, 1]]}, {y, 
  Min@d00[[All, 2]], Max@d00[[All, 2]]}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, testpoint[d00, {x, y}]]]
DensityPlot[
 pyfunc[x, y], {x, Min@d00[[All, 1]], Max@d00[[All, 1]]}, {y, 
  Min@d00[[All, 2]], Max@d00[[All, 2]]}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, testpoint[d00, {x, y}]]]
```

You can get the initial momenta for all your interior points via

```
data3 = {#1, #2, pxfunc[#1, #2], pyfunc[#1, #2]} & @@@ data2;
```

Comment: I do not want to plot them! Is it possible to obtain a new list, let's say, `data3` with four columns $(x,y,p_x,p_y)$ for all the orbits inside the curve?

Comment: How do you know if the orbits for conditions within your shape will also "close up", @Vaggelis?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z - I believe I answered the question "how can I interpolate the $p_x$ and $p_y$ of the orbit by taking into account the values of the boundary?" As to how to go from the initial `(px,py)` values to orbits, that shouldn't be too hard to accomplish, but it's a different question entirely

Comment: Indeed you answered the question and I will accept it. However the output is not the desired one. I want a new list `data3` containing all four elements $(x,y,p_x,p_y)$. Could you add an update about it?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z - now for that I'm not sure offhand how to go about it.  If you choose a random point in space, `{x0, y0}` that is inside the orbit given, then you can use your interpolating function here to get some initial momenta `{px0,py0}`, but I can't say what the dynamics following that would be just based on the data from one orbit.  You need to add in some equations of motion, and then use `NDSolve` or something similar to get the orbit from the initial conditions...

Comment: If I try `data3 = Table[{data2[[i, 1]], data2[[i, 2]], 
    pxfunc[data2[[i, 1]], data2[[i, 2]]], 
    pyfunc[data2[[i, 1]], data2[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, Length[data2]}];` would it be correct?

Comment: Ahhhh, I get what you mean now.  Sorry to be dense.

Comment: I use your interpolation functions so to obtain the px and pY for every orbit inside the closed curve. The above definition of `data3`, is it correct?

Comment: It is I think, it is much shorter to write `{#1, #2, pxfunc[#1, #2], pyfunc[#1, #2]} & @@@ data2`