# Interpolating initial conditions of orbits

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

I have a [data file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ma4lhlh9rd64oib/nhim2.dat) containing the $(x,y,p_x,p_y)$ initial conditions of two-dimensional orbits.

Let's plot them on the $(x,y)$ plane.

```
data0 = Import["nhim2.dat", "Table"];
d0 = data0[[All, {1, 2}]];
S0 = ListPlot[d0, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.003]}]
```

[image]

Then we define some random $(x_0,y_0)$ initial conditions on the same plane

```
data = {{0.9896, -0.29035}, {0.9214, 0.20255}, {0.96015, 0.39785},   
        {0.96325, 0.325}, {1.0764, 0.0367}, {1.00045, 0.2227}, 
        {0.8253, -0.3167}, {1.0361, 0.36065}, {0.83925, -0.02685},
        {1.02525, -0.34305}, {1.0113, 0.10645}, {1.0082, -0.1431}, 
        {0.8284, 0.22115}, {0.90435, 0.13435}, {0.90125, -0.1369}, 
        {1.0206, 0.2475}, {1.1198, -0.02685}, {0.816, 0.2909}, 
        {0.8966, 0.3839}, {0.8129, 0.1049}};

S1 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.015]}];
Show[{S0, S1}]
```

[image]

My question is the following: How can I use the initial `data0` as a base in order to interpolate the $p_x$ and $p_y$ of the 20 random $(x_0,y_0)$ initial conditions? The aim is to create a new list, `data2`, containing in four columns the $(x,y,p_x,p_y)$ of the 20 points.

I use version 9 of Mathematica in Win XP SP3.

Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

The answer proposed by @JasonB seems to work. However for this [data file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/vxn8uwuct6bcjn5/nhim33.dat) there are some issues.

Now the initial conditions on the $(x,y)$ look like

[image]

```
data0 = Import["nhim33.dat","Table"];
d1 = GatherBy[data0, #[[;; 2]] &] // GatherBy[#, Length] & // Last // 
     Flatten[#, 1] &;
Length[d1]
```

I end up with only 48 points from the initial 27407.

Then the

```
pyfunc = Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #4} & @@@ d1, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
pxfunc = Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@ d1, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

cannot be evaluated without errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible to easily split up data0 into sublists for the individual orbits?

Comment: @JasonB Unfortunately no. `data0` is just a bunch of initial conditions. In this case, they form nice ellipses but in other case they are randomly scattered points. If we use `Interpolation[data0]` would it work?

Comment: Then I'm confused how this differs from the previous question (I had thought the ellipses were orbits and you wanted to interpolate orbits).  Just from reading, I would recommend the same strategy as in that question - make an interpolating function on the unstructured grid given by `d0`.  Also, your `data0` doesn't have the `px` or `py` values.

Comment: @JasonB I just uploaded the correct file. The interpolation should take into account the px and py of `data0` and then apply it to the random 20 initial conditions. I think that this is different form the previous case. Anyway, provide an answer so as to see whether we mean the say the same thing!

Comment: @JasonB When I try `pyfunc = Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #4} & @@@ data0, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]` I get the following error message: "Interpolation::indp: There are duplicated abscissa points in ..."

Comment: That's because you **do** have duplicate abscissa points :-)

Comment: See the result of `GatherBy[data0, #[[;; 2]] &] // SortBy[Length] // Last` and you'll see the same x and y values with different `py` values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. You have some duplicate coordinates in your data, these need to be removed before you can interpolate
2. A couple of the points in your list are outside the range you've specified.  Therefore you need to extrapolate, not interpolate, and the results at these points can't be trusted.

```
data0 = DeleteDuplicatesBy[data0, #[[;; 2]] &];
pyfunc = Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #4} & @@@ data0, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
pxfunc = Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@ data0, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1]; 

data2 = {#1, #2, pxfunc[#1, #2], 
    pyfunc[#1, #2]} & @@@ {{0.9896, -0.29035}, {0.9214, 
    0.20255}, {0.96015, 0.39785}, {0.96325, 0.325}, {1.0764, 
    0.0367}, {1.00045, 0.2227}, {0.8253, -0.3167}, {1.0361, 
    0.36065}, {0.83925, -0.02685}, {1.02525, -0.34305}, {1.0113, 
    0.10645}, {1.0082, -0.1431}, {0.8284, 0.22115}, {0.90435, 
    0.13435}, {0.90125, -0.1369}, {1.0206, 
    0.2475}, {1.1198, -0.02685}, {0.816, 0.2909}, {0.8966, 
    0.3839}, {0.8129, 0.1049}}
(* {{0.9896, -0.29035, 0.0551768, 0.80115}, {0.9214, 
  0.20255, -0.0651558, 1.11407}, {0.96015, 0.39785, -0.0828736, 
  0.83324}, {0.96325, 0.325, -0.0722046, 0.878227}, {1.0764, 
  0.0367, -0.00358338, 0.546399}, {1.00045, 0.2227, -0.0414146, 
  0.797068}, {0.8253, -0.3167, 0.152263, 1.40477}, {1.0361, 
  0.36065, -0.0430032, 0.554697}, {0.83925, -0.02685, 0.0143835, 
  1.49376}, {1.02525, -0.34305, 0.045252, 0.63029}, {1.0113, 
  0.10645, -0.0194832, 0.796962}, {1.0082, -0.1431, 0.0264175, 
  0.799015}, {0.8284, 0.22115, -0.116249, 1.46361}, {0.90435, 
  0.13435, -0.0493386, 1.21041}, {0.90125, -0.1369, 0.0511158, 
  1.22164}, {1.0206, 0.2475, -0.0380753, 0.705899}, {1.1198, -0.02685,
   0.00127011, 0.370953}, {0.816, 0.2909, -0.147451, 
  1.44989}, {0.8966, 0.3839, -0.121433, 1.07842}, {0.8129, 
  0.1049, -0.0633001, 1.58377}} *)
```

For version 9, here is another way of getting the duplicate-abscissa free version:

```
data0 = GatherBy[data0, #[[;; 2]] &] // GatherBy[#, Length] & // 
    Last // Flatten[#, 1] &;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `DeleteDuplicatesBy` is not recognized in v9

Comment: Try using the much slower two-argument version of `DeleteDuplicates` - `DeleteDuplicates[data0, #1[[;; 2]] == #2[[;; 2]] &]`

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z - see the edit for a faster version.

Comment: When I evaluate `data2 = {#1, #2, pxfunc[#1, #2], 
    pyfunc[#1, #2]} & @@@ data` I get the error message "InterpolatingFunction::dmval: "Input value {0.9896,-0.29035} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used" and then all py form the new list is 0.

Comment: I get that error, but I do get answers as well.  I'm using a different version 9 so maybe that's the trouble.  Why don't you just [remove the points](http://pastebin.com/raw/Quk9v7Gu) that are outside the original region?

Comment: Please take a look at my update!

Comment: I will have to take a look at it after work, I'll get back to you then

Comment: @ Any news regarding the second data file? :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a full answer, but it seems to me that you may have a use for code that allows you to group the points by the orbit they belong to, as Jason also mentioned. It seems to me that, with this in hand, the problem may be reduced to the one [@JasonB solved](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119177/27951) in [your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119168/27951).

Here's a start in that direction:

```
paths = FindClusters[data0, 15, Method -> "Agglomerate"];
ListPlot@paths
ListPlot /@ paths
```

[image: all together]
[image: singles]