# Visibility Graph of Polygon

Tags: graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry

Could anyone provide a function that takes a polygon as input and outputs its visibility graph ? [Visibility Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility_graph)

If not, is there a function that checks whether a line segment lies inside a polygon?

Comment: Example? Even a small one as a sketch?

Comment: So regarding your second question.. You want to verify if segment intersects with polygon's edges and its vertex is inside, correct? You can start [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/how-to-check-if-a-2d-point-is-in-a-polygon/9417#9417) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)

Comment: @Öskå  for example if you take a convex polygon, any two vertices (which dont share a polygon edge)  can "see" each other (because all the points on their line segment lie inside the polygon). So, the visibility graph will be a clique on the vertices of the input polygon.

Comment: @BlacKow i want to verify if the line segments between any two vertices i,j of the polygon lie inside the polygon boundary completely . 

 While there is a function that checks for a specific point lying inside, its input must be constants (looks like). I thought of using the segment formula on the line segment to check ForAll points using that function but it fails.

InPolyQ function on this page : [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/how-to-check-if-a-2d-point-is-in-a-polygon/9417#9417]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `RegionDifference` and `RegionMeasure` functions can be parlayed into a function that looks at whether a given line segment lies inside a given region of a plane.  Basically, you use `RegionDifference` to find a representation of the part of each line segment that lies outside the polygon, and then use `RegionMeasure` to calculate its length.  If the result is zero, then the line lies inside the polygon, and so we have an edge in the visibility graph.  Here's an example:

```
pts = {{0.662494051836106`,  0.39007247052752403`}, {0.1837087927842842`,  0.38632927614895274`}, {0.7310240254669638`, 0.8628672998019931`}, {0.8896898456472895`, 0.6441236848987553`}, {0.7560380846919499`, 0.13152467108636823`}, {0.2554583695590438`, 0.16840295208595313`}}
Graphics[{Red, Polygon[pts], Black, Table[Text[i, pts[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[pts]}]}]
```

[image]

```
lines = Outer[Line[{#1, #2}] &, pts, pts, 1];
adjmat = Map[ Boole[RegionMeasure[RegionDifference[#, Polygon[pts]]] == 0] &, lines, {2}] - IdentityMatrix[Length[pts]];
AdjacencyGraph[adjmat, VertexLabels -> "Index"]
```

[image]

A few notes on this construction:

- `lines` contains all the lines connecting all pairs of points in the polygon, in an $n \times n$ matrix.  ($n$ is the number of points of the polygon.)
- `adjmat` is constructed by testing whether the amount of each element of `line` lying outside the polygon is zero or non-zero.  The equality test yields `True` or `False`, which is then converted to `1` or `0` respectively by `Boole`.  We then subtract the identity matrix to specify that we are not viewing each vertex as visible to itself (though if you are, then you should eliminate the last piece of this line.

This code takes about 30 seconds to run on my machine (a two-year-old iMac), so it's not particularly quick;  it could probably be optimized quite a bit.

---

**EDIT:** if you want the resulting graph to have the points laid out as they are in the polygon, you can either use `GraphPlot` with the `VertexCoordinateRules` option (as described by @HarshaTirumala in the comments), or use the `VertexCoordinates` option for `AdjacencyGraph`:

```
AdjacencyGraph[adjmat, VertexLabels -> "Index", VertexCoordinates -> pts, VertexSize -> Tiny]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. optimisation is not an issue as i only want the end result. even my Mac took around 30 seconds.

Can the matrix be drawn on the polygon skeleton? im new to mathematica so not sure of how to proceed with it although i believe it would be possible.

Comment: @HarshaTirumala: I don't have a version of Mathematica here at home, but I think if you replace the last command with `AdjacencyGraph[adjmat, VertexLabels -> "Index", VertexCoordinateRules -> pts]` you'll get a graph with the points laid out at their "true" locations.  Alternately, you could use `Select` to pick out the interior lines out of `lines` and use `Graphics` to render them.  If I have time tomorrow, I'll update this answer.

Comment: AdjacencyGraph doesn't have VertexCoordinateRules as an option. But graphplot does; so this piece of code did work :  `GraphPlot[adjmat, VertexCoordinateRules -> pts]` . Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @HarshaTirumala:  I had no idea that `GraphPlot` accepted adjacency matrices to construct graphs, so thanks for the tip!  Now that I have a copy of MM to play with, I found a way to do it with `AdjacencyGraph` as well;  see my edited answer.

Comment: ``adjmat = Map[Boole[Region`RegionSubset[#, Polygon[pts]]] &, 
    lines, {2}] - IdentityMatrix[Length[pts]];``

Answer (score 4):

This code is not as pretty as Michael Seifert's, but I think it runs a bit faster.

Essentially, when looking at any two vertices, we first decide whether the line connecting them is part of the polygon boundary.  If so, that is an edge to the graph.  If not, we look at the length of the line that is inside the polygon, and if it is equal to the total length of the line, that is an edge to the graph.  Here is the function

```
visibilityGraph[pts_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{lines, vis},
   lines = Sort /@ Transpose[{pts, RotateRight@pts}];
   vis[a_, b_] :=
    If[MemberQ[lines, Sort[pts[[{a, b}]]]],
     True,
     RegionMeasure[
       RegionIntersection[Line[pts[[{a, b}]]], Polygon@pts]] == 
      ArcLength[Line[pts[[{a, b}]]]]
     ];
   Graph[Range@Length@pts,
    #1 <-> #2 & @@@
     Select[
      Subsets[Range@Length@pts, {2}],
      vis @@ # &], opts]
   ];
visibilityGraph[poly_Polygon, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 visibilityGraph[First@poly, opts]
```

Here it is applied to the polygon from the answer above,

```
visibilityGraph[pts, VertexLabels -> "Name"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And here it is applied to a set of random concave polygons (and here I'm putting the polygon in the background and using the points as the vertex coordinates for the graph)

```
pgons = Get[
   "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jasondbiggs/\
59cb7d4aa802bde68c9f6a5203ef698f/raw/\
8b3768422fdcc5c28d03cd1d7a5361c0a1d2d15a/gistfile1.txt"];

Show[Graphics[{Red, Opacity[0.5], #}],
   visibilityGraph[#, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
    VertexCoordinates -> First@#], ImageSize -> 200
   ] & /@ pgons
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nicely done.  My impression is that `RegionIntersection` and `RegionMeasure` need a lot more computational power to figure out that a line passes along the edge of a given region that they do to figure out that a line passes through the interior;  so avoiding the calls to these functions in the case of the exterior edges of the polygon should save a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you :-).  This method could still have a problem, if the line in question has a length exactly 2, then [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116083/9490) could cause a false positive

Answer (score 1):

> If not, is there a function that checks whether a line segment lies
> inside a polygon?

```
WolframLanguageData["RegionWithin", {"VersionIntroduced", 
  "DateIntroduced"}]
```

[image]

---

Using data from Michael Seifert's answer:

```
pts = {{0.662494051836106`, 
   0.39007247052752403`}, {0.1837087927842842`, 
   0.38632927614895274`}, {0.7310240254669638`, 
   0.8628672998019931`}, {0.8896898456472895`, 
   0.6441236848987553`}, {0.7560380846919499`, 
   0.13152467108636823`}, {0.2554583695590438`, 0.16840295208595313`}}

poly = Polygon@pts;
x = Subsets[Range[Length@pts], {2}];
t = Line /@ (Part[pts, #] & /@ x);
sel = Pick[t, RegionWithin[poly, #] & /@ t];

Graphics[{
  Opacity[0.6, Yellow], Polygon@pts
  , Brown, t
  , Blue, Thick, sel
  }]
```

[image]