# Inconsistent behavior from RegionMeasure on the RegionIntersection between a Polygon and a Line

Tags: regions, polygons

Consider a `Polygon` with lines drawn between two of its vertices,

```
pgon = Get[
    "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jasondbiggs/\
59cb7d4aa802bde68c9f6a5203ef698f/raw/\
8b3768422fdcc5c28d03cd1d7a5361c0a1d2d15a/gistfile1.txt"][[2]];
pts = pgon[[1]];
pair1 = {2, 4};
pair2 = {2, 7};
Graphics[{Red, 
  pgon, {Blue, Line[pts[[#]]], Green, PointSize[Large], 
     Point[pts[[#]]]} & /@ {pair1, pair2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly one of the lines lies entirely within the polygon, while the other touches the polygon at its endpoints.  We can ask for the intersections between these regions

```
intersections = 
 RegionIntersection[Line[pts[[#]]], pgon] & /@ {pair1, pair2}
(* {RegionIntersection[
  Line[{{7.52229, 9.31563}, {7.93484, 4.23025}}], 
  Polygon[{{9.23481, 8.12637}, {7.52229, 9.31563}, {8.39443, 
     4.79338}, {7.93484, 4.23025}, {6.00149, 1.75529}, {7.75656, 
     2.24465}, {9.438, 3.48553}}]], 
 RegionIntersection[Line[{{7.52229, 9.31563}, {9.438, 3.48553}}], 
  Polygon[{{9.23481, 8.12637}, {7.52229, 9.31563}, {8.39443, 
     4.79338}, {7.93484, 4.23025}, {6.00149, 1.75529}, {7.75656, 
     2.24465}, {9.438, 3.48553}}]]} *)
```

Ideally, the system would return either `Line` or `Point` objects, but it doesn't.  We could then ask for the `RegionMeasure` of these intersections, to determine whether either of the lines is contained by the polygons,

```
RegionMeasure /@ intersections
(* {2., 6.13677} *)
```

The first result is the number of 0-dimensional points at which an intersection occurs, and the second result is the length of the line.

This seems inconsistent.  In trying to define a function to determine whether the line lies within the polygon, I would like to get a zero for the case where the line has zero length inside.

I get no help from `ArcLength`, `RegionDimension`, or `RegionEmbeddingDimension`

```
ArcLength /@ intersections
RegionDimension /@ intersections
RegionEmbeddingDimension /@ intersections
(* {2., 6.13677} *)
(* {1, 1} *)
(* {2, 2} *)
```

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: In the case of `RegionMeasure` it is expected, it is mentioned under "possible issues" in the documentation.

Comment: Couldn't you say with a very high probability that the region measure will not be exactly 2 if the line intersects the polygon?

Comment: That was what I was doing before, but then [I decided](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116087/9490) to just say that if the `ArcLength` of the `Intersection` was the same as the length of the line, then it is in the polygon.  It still seems like a non-foolproof method, as there can be cases where the line has a length of exactly 2.

Comment: @C.E. - I could delete the question (since I didn't read the Possible Issues).  I still think the system could respond better to this request, and it seems that `ArcLength` and `RegionDimension` are just wrong in this case.  I had seen [this method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66157/9490) but it fails for the case above.  I could rephrase the question to be about `RegionDimension`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118398/9490).  In that case you are looking at the 1-dimensional overlap between 2-dimensional regions and taking its measure.  Here you are looking at the intersection between a 1D and a 2D region and taking its measure.  Both of these cases can be considered "near singular", to borrow a phrase from one of the developers, and it is even mentioned as one of the "possible issues" of `RegionMeasure`.

But the result of `ArcLength` is definitely wrong, and the fact that it doesn't even give an error message means this is a bug.  I can guess that the function that decides how the arc length should be calculated and the function that is called to calculate the arc length react differently to finite-precision representations of near-singular regions.

But we can use the same method as suggested by illian [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119119/9490) to get around this issue.  Essentially we need to convert the numbers in the `Polygon` and the `Line` to exact numbers via `exact[p_]:=SetPrecision[p,∞]` or `exact[p_]:= Rationalize[p, 0]` and get the `ArcLength` via

```
ArcLength /@ exact[intersections] // N
(* {0., 6.13677} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there has been some progress on this issue. This is what I get in M11.2:

```
intersections = RegionIntersection[Line[pts[[#]]],pgon]&/@{pair1,pair2}
```

> {Point[{{7.52229, 9.31563}, {7.93484, 4.23025}}], 
>    Line[{{7.52229, 9.31563}, {9.438, 3.48553}}]}