# Finding area of intersection regions

Tags: computational-geometry, intersection, polygons

I want to be able to find the area of the intersection between a hexagon and a slice. I have tried `RegionMeasure` or `Area` but I seem to get incorrect answers. `RegionMeasure` gives length when the intersection is a line, so I switched to `Area` but sometimes it still gives weird answers, when the intersection happens to be a line.

One reason why I think this might occur is that I build the hexagon using `Polygon`, but the "slice" is with `Disk`. Is that the problem? How to I make a region as a slice, so that `Area[RegionIntersection[hexagon, slice]]` between the two regions will always give $0$ for a line intersection and no intersection, i.e. return a nonzero result only for 2D intersection.

See picture. I want to know the area of intersection of the black hexagon will each of the 6 (colored for visualization) slices below. The answer should be non-zero for the 2 upper left slices, and 0 for every other slice, even though some have "line intersections".

[image: the objects]

Thanks.

EDIT:
The problem is that edges get non-zero measure. Why is the below code giving .7, and not 0?

```
DiskR = 1.5;
Show[
  Graphics[{Orange, Opacity[0.35], 
  Disk[{0, 0}, DiskR, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/6}]}], 
  Graphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, .7}, {-1, 1}}]]]
```

and

```
Area[
 RegionIntersection[
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, .7}, {-1, 1}}], 
  Disk[{0, 0}, DiskR, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/6}]
 ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: This certainly works: `Polygon[CirclePoints[{-(Sqrt[3]/2), 1/2}, {1, π/6}, 6]] ~RegionIntersection~ Disk[{0, 0}, 3, {π/2, π/2 + π/3}] // Area`

Comment: But why does a line give non-zero Area? See my edited question.

Comment: Please post the code as text. Nobody wants to copy it out manually from the image.

Comment: Sorry, new here. But I see your point. I edited and pasted the code.

Comment: You didn't include the value of `DiskR`, but replacing `DiskR` with 3/2 seems to give something similar to your last figure. However, I can't reproduce your last result: `Area[
 RegionIntersection[
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, .7}, {-1, 1}}],
  Disk[{0, 0}, 3/2, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/6}]
  ]
 ]` returns $0$ as you expected, not $0.7$ as you reported ([results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jtIH7.png)). I am using MMA 10.4 on Win7-64. What version are you using?

Comment: This seems buggy - if you set `DiskR= 1.5` then you get the [erroneous result from the OP](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yp3i.png), but if you set `DiskR=3/2` (or use `Rationalize@DiskR` in the call to `Disk`) then you get the [right answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YzGVL.png) of `0`

Comment: Yes, when I run DiskR=1.5 (or 2.0 or whatever), I also get 0.7. But using DiskR=3/2 gives 0. If this is a bug, hopeful Mathematica can see this and fix it. I don't know how to report it, though.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the intersection between two 2D regions is a 1D region - a line.  It makes sense that the functions that are called by `RegionMeasure` and `RegionIntersection` might be influenced by roundoff errors associated with using floating point numbers rather than exact numbers.

So a workaround is to convert your expressions to use exact numbers prior to taking the area.  I had originally used `Rationalize` to do this, and it works in this case, but it doesn't always.  So we can borrow a [function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119119/9490) from illian that is a bit more robust

```
sp = Function[p, SetPrecision[p, Infinity]];    
DiskR = 1.0; 
Area[
 RegionIntersection[sp@Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, .7}, {-1, 1}}], 
  sp@Disk[{0, 0}, DiskR, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/6}]]]

(* 0 *)
```

While this behavior is understandable, I'd still say it's a bug