# RegionIntersection puzzle

Tags: computational-geometry, regions

I am using `RegionIntersection[]` to intersect two rectangles, phrased
as `Polygon[]`s:

---

[image: BugRegInt]

---

`RegionIntersection[]` returns an incorrect result (the green region above; detail below),
and issues a series of error messages:

---

[image: Errors]

---

Here is the region returned as the intersection, which is not correct
(it should be a quadrilateral):

```
Polygon[{{0.407273, 0.650444}, {0.509656, -0.0200315}, {0.998507, 
   0.0546171}, {0.640904, 0.767621}, {0.998507, 0.0546171}}]
```

Here it is as a line drawing:

---

[image: PentQuad]

---

Here is the originating call that produces the incorrect intersection:

```
RegionIntersection[
 Polygon[{{0.5096555454081809`, -0.02003146973392257`}, \
{0.9985073695269602`, 0.05461714932464575`}, {0.6966031018052412`, 
    2.0316992956026936`}, {0.2077512776864619`, 
    1.9570506765441251`}}] , 
 Polygon[{{0.9985073695269602`, 
    0.05461714932464575`}, {0.6409040075686694`, 
    0.767621034809768`}, {-1.1468443539373534`, \
-0.12901478643123643`}, {-0.7892409919790626`, -0.8420186719163586`}}]
 ]
```

Can anyone see what's going on?

Comment: (In case it matters: I'm running 10.4.0.0 under MacOS.)

Comment: I can reproduce this, and it looks like a bug to me. A workaround seems to be to change the last digit in 0.9985073695269603` of the second polygon to 0.9985073695269604`, Apparently Mathematica doesn't like the two polygons to gave a shared point.

Comment: v12.2.0 on Win7-x64 doesn't have this bug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed in the development version. For a possible workaround, use exact coordinates, for example

```
sp = Function[p, SetPrecision[p, Infinity]];

ri = RegionIntersection[
 sp@Polygon[{{0.5096555454081809`, -0.02003146973392257`}, 
             {0.9985073695269602`, 0.05461714932464575`}, 
             {0.6966031018052412`, 2.0316992956026936`},   
             {0.2077512776864619`, 1.9570506765441251`}}], 
 sp@Polygon[{{0.9985073695269602`, 0.05461714932464575`}, 
             {0.6409040075686694`, 0.767621034809768`},    
             {-1.1468443539373534`, -0.12901478643123643`}, 
             {-0.7892409919790626`, -0.8420186719163586`}}]];

N[ri]

(* Polygon[{{0.40727258068338046`, 0.6504444171024929`}, 
            {0.5096555454081809`, -0.02003146973392257`}, 
            {0.9985073695269602`, 0.05461714932464575`}, 
            {0.6409040075686694`, 0.767621034809768`}}] *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Floating-point computations strike again.

Comment: @ilian - I just noticed that if you cyclicly permute the data points then it will work using the usual precision.  Very odd....

Comment: @ilian - is there any difference between your `sp` function and using `Rationalize[#, 0]&`?

Comment: @JasonB Yes, these are different. `Rationalize` does a continued fraction-based approximation, while `SetPrecision` works directly off the internal bit representation. There should be an example in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) (under Properties & Relations).

Comment: @ilian Will this fix be included in the next minor update or do we have to wait until v11 (or is that the next update)?

Comment: @Cassini Yes, the (very) soon to be released 11.0.

Comment: @ilian Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround is to turn the polygons into `MeshRegion`s first,

```
RegionIntersection @@ (DiscretizeGraphics /@ {p1, p2}) // 
  MeshPrimitives[#, 2] & // First
(* Polygon[{{0.407273, 
   0.650444}, {0.509656, -0.0200315}, {0.998507, 
   0.0546171}, {0.640904, 0.767621}}] *)
```

Where `p1` and `p2` are your polygons

### Edit - more odd behavior

What's even odder is that if you change the order of the points of the polygon (cyclicly so that you don't change the shape), then it will work.  If `points1` and `points2` are the points of the polygon in the OP, then

```
RegionIntersection @@ (Polygon /@ {points1, points2})
```

fails as it did for OP, but

```
RegionIntersection @@ (Polygon /@ {RotateLeft@points1, 
RotateLeft@points2})
```

works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, Jason! Can you explain why this circumvents the problem?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke - I wish I could!  I just have had some experience with regions lately, and one of the basic steps when trying anything is to try it on a `MeshRegion` versus a regular region.  For it to work on a `Polygon` or other built in shape (like `Circle` or `Disk`), I think the R&D guys have to code the cases in individually.  But when using a `MeshRegion` there is a general toolkit that is used.  @ilian would know more about that than I do though....

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke - so if you are working in 2D with a non-infinite region, then turning it into a `MeshRegion` with `DiscretizeGraphics` is often a great way to go.  But if you are working in 3D, then it won't work.