# Defining a Boolean Region

Tags: graphics, regions, boolean-computation, logic, regionplot

I'd like to define a new region that is "within direct sight" of a certain point within an existing region.

For the example below, the regions highlighted in red from the black point are not directly visible, and hence should not be included in the region. The remaining blue area should define the new region.

```
hatpolykite = LaminaData["HatPolykite"];
region = hatpolykite["BoundaryMeshRegion"][1];
SeedRandom[1];
point = RandomPoint[region];
pointgraphics = Point[point]
Show[{RegionPlot[region], Graphics[pointgraphics]}]
```

[image]

I've been trying to create a `BooleanRegion` to define this new region. The region should be defined by

1. Are the points within the new region within the first region, i.e. `RegionMember[region,point]==True`

AND

2. There is no intersection with the point in the new region and the first region boundary, `RegionIntersection[ RegionBoundary[region],Line[ (*all lines between *) RegionBoundary[region], point]]=={}`.

The last logical condition is giving me trouble.

Comment: Maybe https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/290138/72111?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Avoid using `White` to fill the ouside.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
hatpolykite = LaminaData["HatPolykite"];
region = hatpolykite["BoundaryMeshRegion"][1];
bd = RegionBounds[region];
{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}} = ScalingTransform[1.5*{1, 1}, Mean /@ bd]@bd;
space0 = Rectangle[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}];
obstacles0 = RegionDifference[space0, region];
domain = region;
lines = MeshPrimitives[domain, 1][[;; , 1]];
L = 15;
shadow[loc_, line_] := 
  Polygon[{line[[1]] + L*Normalize[line[[1]] - loc], line[[1]], 
    line[[2]], line[[2]] + L*Normalize[line[[2]] - loc]}];
loc = RandomPoint[region];
regA = Fold[RegionDifference, region, shadow[loc, #] & /@ lines];
regB = RegionDifference[region, regA];
Graphics[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue], region}, {Yellow, regA}, {Gray,
    regB}, Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point@loc}]
```

[image]

- Animation.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
hatpolykite = LaminaData["HatPolykite"];
region = hatpolykite["BoundaryMeshRegion"][1];
bd = RegionBounds[region];
{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}} = ScalingTransform[1.2*{1, 1}, Mean /@ bd]@bd;
space0 = Rectangle[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}];
obstacles0 = RegionDifference[space0, region];
domain = region;
lines = MeshPrimitives[domain, 1][[;; , 1]];
L = 15;
shadow[loc_, line_] := 
  Polygon[{line[[1]] + L*Normalize[line[[1]] - loc], line[[1]], 
    line[[2]], line[[2]] + L*Normalize[line[[2]] - loc]}];
Manipulate[
 Module[{regA, regB},
  regA = Fold[RegionDifference, region, shadow[loc, #] & /@ lines];
  regB = RegionDifference[region, regA]; 
  Graphics[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue], region}, {Yellow, 
     regA}, {Gray, regB}, Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point@loc}, 
   PlotRange -> {{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}}]], {{loc, {1, 1}}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> Function[pos, loc = RegionNearest[domain]@pos], 
  Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{0, 0}]}]}]
```

**Original**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
hatpolykite = LaminaData["HatPolykite"];
region = hatpolykite["BoundaryMeshRegion"][1];
bd = RegionBounds[region];
{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}} = ScalingTransform[1.5*{1, 1}, Mean /@ bd]@bd;
space0 = Rectangle[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}];
obstacles0 = RegionDifference[space0, region];
domain = region;
lines = MeshPrimitives[domain, 1][[;; , 1]];
L = 15;
shadow[loc_, line_] := 
  Polygon[{line[[1]] + L*Normalize[line[[1]] - loc], line[[1]], 
    line[[2]], line[[2]] + L*Normalize[line[[2]] - loc]}];
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Orange, space0, AbsolutePointSize[10], Red, Point@loc, 
   Black, shadow[loc, #] & /@ lines, White, obstacles0}, 
  PlotRange -> RegionBounds[domain]], {{loc, {8, 1}}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> Function[pos, loc = RegionNearest[domain]@pos], 
  Appearance -> 
   Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{0, 0}]}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The top ranked answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/290138/72111) doesn't immediately work.

A lower ranked answer does satisfy my requirements.

```
hatpolykite = LaminaData["HatPolykite"];
region = hatpolykite["BoundaryMeshRegion"][1];
SeedRandom[1];
vertices = hatpolykite["Vertices"][1][[1]];

{minx, maxx} = {Min[Flatten[vertices[[;; , 1]]]], 
   Max[Flatten[vertices[[;; , 1]]]]};
{miny, maxy} = {Min[Flatten[vertices[[;; , 2]]]], 
   Max[Flatten[vertices[[;; , 2]]]]};


reg = region;
point = RandomPoint[region];
reg2 = Line[{point, {x, y}}];
cond = RegionWithin[reg, reg2];

RegionPlot[cond, {x, minx, maxx}, {y, miny, maxy}, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
 PlotPoints -> 30, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][3], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thin, Black], 
 Prolog -> {{Opacity[0.4, Brown], reg}}, 
 Epilog -> {{Black, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point@point}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you have renamed `loc` to `point` but forgot to change it in `RegionPlot`, so now the black dot does not match the green solution :)