# How can I plot this spirally surface?

Tags: plotting, function-construction

I would like to plot a surface that looks something like this sand spiral.

[image]

But I really have no idea how. Ideally I would like to be able to express this as a function in cartesian coordinates. I'm not looking for the granularity or anything, I just want a smooth spirally surface.

Comment: Would a surface like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mAfjV.png) be acceptable as well?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A manual way of doing it is:

```
Plot3D[With[{ϕ = ArcTan[x, y], r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, 
  0.3 Sin[2 π r + ϕ]]
  , {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}
  , BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 25, MaxRecursion -> 4
]
```

[image: Sand Spiral]

The reasoning behind the code is as follows:
We know we want to start with some ripples radiating outwards, something like

$$\mathrm{height}(r) = h_0 \sin(r).$$

`Plot3D` gives us the cartesian `{x,y}` coordinates though, where we can evaluate our function. So we first need to express radius $r$ and for completeness and later use also our polar angle $\phi$ in terms of `{x,y}` which, when we investigate or [look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) we find:

$$r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$\phi = \arctan(y/x),$$

which leads us to

```
Plot3D[With[{ϕ = ArcTan[x, y], r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, 
  0.3 Sin[5 r]]
  , {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}
  , BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> None
  , PlotPoints -> 25, MaxRecursion -> 4
]
```

[image: Radial ripples]

Almost there!

Now what we see in the reference what is still missing in the simple outward ripples is that as we go around the center the ripples shift outwards, which means that, additionally to the radius we want the effective phase in the outward rippling to also grow with the polar angle.

$$\mathrm{height}(r,\phi) = h_0 \sin(a\,r+\phi).$$

Mathematically this depicts an [Archimedean Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral).

Also we can choose a different factor for the `r` part in the phase, $2\pi$ is only one arbitrary value. We can get steeper or more shallow spirals with different factors.

Comment: "Manual"? I was expecting from you solving Einstein's equation for merging black holes :) A propos [9405](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/how-to-check-if-a-2d-point-is-in-a-polygon/9418#9418)

Comment: @Kuba :D haha, i'm still an apprentice in black hole merging though ;)

Comment: Nice to see you posting again! :-)

Comment: This is just what I wanted! Thank you very much and thank you for the fantastically clear explanation.

Answer (score 17):

You may want to plot `z(r, fi) = sin (r + fi)`

```
p = 20;
Plot3D[
  Evaluate @ Sin @ Tr @ CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Polar", {x, y}], 
  {x, -p, p}, {y, -p, p}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

```
p = 30.;
n = 9 10^4;
pts = Catenate@Array[List, Sqrt[n] {1, 1}, {{-p, p}, {-p, p}}] + 
   RandomReal[.2, n];

MapThread[ Append, 
  {pts, 
   Sin @ Total[ CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Polar", pts], {2}]
  }
] //  Sphere[#, .2] & // Graphics3D[#, Lighting -> {{"Directional", 
  RGBColor[1, .7, .1], {{5, 5, 4}, {5, 5, 0}}}}] &
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this is similar to mine, but I didn't recognize it at first. Nice texture, too. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, not very efficient but I wanted to see how it looks :) Well, all are similar but each brings something, in this respect mine is the least educational :)

Comment: Wow! I didn't really need the sandy effect but this is awesome!

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way that looks more like sand spirals with the tide coming in:

```
With[{d = 42, n = 150}, 
 ReliefPlot[
  Cos@Table[
    Through[(Abs + Arg)[x + I y]], {x, -d, d, d/n}, {y, -d, d, d/n}]]]
```

[image]

As a side note, if you want to see a physics phenomenon where such Archimedean spirals occur, you may find [this link to my web page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/eikonals/) interesting.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke Yes, I just `Through` it in for fun...

Answer (score 4):

Thies's solution is excellent. This was the best I could do with a logarithmic spiral:

```
With[{ψ = 87°}, 
     Plot3D[Tanh[(x Sin[Tan[ψ] Log[x^2 + y^2]/2] + y Cos[Tan[ψ] Log[x^2 + y^2]/2])/10],
            {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, Axes -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None,
            Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
            ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SandyTerrain", Clip[#3 + 1/4, {0, 3/4}]] &),
            Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 105, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: I hope it looks somewhat sandy at least.]

Answer (score 4):

Any wave form could be used:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], 0.2 TriangleWave[r - t/(2 Pi)]},
 {r, 0, 6}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> {121, 30}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], Sin[r - t]}, {r, 0, 60}, {t, 0, 
  2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> {121, 30}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

***Etc.***

Answer (score 3):

```
Module[{n = 15, pts},
  pts = Table[{θ Cos[θ], θ Sin[θ], 0}, {θ, 0, n π, π/20}];
  Graphics3D[{GrayLevel[.75], Tube[pts, π]},
    ClipPlanes -> {0, 0, 1, 0},
    Boxed -> False,
    Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

[image: spiral]