# Why does ReliefPlot not have a version for functions?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, numerics, visualization, implementation-details

**TL, DR:** Use the `LightingAngle` option to `DensityPlot` to achieve the same shadows effect as `ReliefPlot`. ([@Brett Champion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/69/brett-champion)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/246084/72025))

---

To plot bivariate functions, we typically either use `Plot3D`, whose dynamic effects allow flexible investigation, or `DensityPlot`, which is better for publications. However, sometimes the output of `DensityPlot` is a little ... obscure(?), and shadows from `ReliefPlot` would add a lot perspective.

> Example from the `ReliefPlot` documentation:
>
> ```
> ReliefPlot[Table[i + Sin[i^2 + j^2], {i, -4, 4, .03}, {j, -4, 4, .03}], ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"]
> ```
>
> [image]

> Compare a replication using `DensityPlot`:
>
> ```
> DensityPlot[i + Sin[i^2 + j^2], {i, -4, 4}, {j, -4, 4}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 40]
> ```
>
> [image]
> Where the well-known oddity of `ReliefPlot`'s orientation can be seen.

For years on MMA SE, a lot of members have used `ReliefPlot` via manual sampling
for function plotting questions
(e.g., [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3683)),
yielding better aesthetic results.
Alternatives include:

- Using `Plot3D` and set the viewpoint at infinity above, but it can also hairy to do. (See [@MichaelE2's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241351/72025) which does this elegantly)
- Manually define normal vectors and do a [normal mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping), which I am not sure how to implement in Mathematica right now. (See [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241442/72025) to get a crude idea)

**But why isn't `ReliefPlot` for functions been officially implemented
(i.e., with adaptive sampling like other `*Plot*` built-ins)?
What is the real technical difficulty?**

P.S.: I believe extensive about this problem can already be found on MMA SE (like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3683) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118898)), but they are scattered everywhere so I am raising this question as a port.

---

For this thread to serve as a guide to others with the same problem,
what are the ways to mimick `ReliefPlot`'s texture?
(please provide simple code and output examples)
From your personal experience,
at what point should one bother to do this for the nicer touch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `LightingAngle` option to `DensityPlot` to achieve the same shadows effect as `ReliefPlot`:

```
DensityPlot[i + Sin[i^2 + j^2], {i, -4, 4}, {j, -4, 4}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotPoints -> 40, 
 LightingAngle -> 180*Degree]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, didn't know this option. According to the document of `LightingAngle`, the default setting of `ReliefPlot` seems to be `LightingAngle -> 3/4 Pi`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  For my example I just used the first suggested completion for the option.

Comment: Neato! I wonder if this option was available all along in recent versions of MMA... Looked back at the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html), wondering why I missed this, and find that `LightingAngle` is listed in the header section, but is lacking from the examples section.

Comment: @Gravifer  It's already there since v7: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Ov4.png Strangely no example is added to the document of `DenistyPlot`.

Answer (score 11):

`ReliefPlot` is using the 3D lighting model (I think) to highlight changes in the gradient.

```
Deploy@Plot3D[i + Sin[i^2 + j^2], {i, -4, 4}, {j, -4, 4}, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"][#3] &), 
  PlotPoints -> 35, MaxRecursion -> 4, Mesh -> None, 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, 
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[0.75]}, {"Directional", 
     GrayLevel[0.15], ImageScaled[{-2, 0, 2}]}, {"Directional", 
     GrayLevel[0.15], ImageScaled[{-2, -2, 2}]}, {"Directional", 
     GrayLevel[0.15], ImageScaled[{0, -2, 2}]}}, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Really elegant results. But I do wonder if `ReliefPlot` actually constructs a 3D surface internally; it is a function often used on large geographic datasets, so actual ray tracing would be quite expensive. I do wonder that if the plot is complicated (e.g., when poles occur), employing `Plot3D` may lead to performance issues. I suspect `ReliefPlot` calculates the gradient of the array and do a [normal mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping) accordingly.

Comment: @Gravifer Well, yeah, of course.  `Plot3D` does not do raytracing either, but calculates the normals (symbolically or numerically, depending on the function). `Graphics3D` uses the normals (not `Plot3D`) and `Lighting` to determine the colors of the polygons. (Unless that is done by the GPU. I'm not really up on exactly what GPUs are used to do.) `ReliefPlot` constructs a `Raster` of the colors that it determines.

Comment: I am a little confused. I just verified that `ReliefPlot` returns a `Graphics` object; does it calls upon `Graphics3D` functionalities internally? I didn't realize that it uses polygon based reflection rendering.

Comment: I don't know how `ReliefPlot` actually does what it does internally, but only inferred it from how well it matches the `Plot3D` output. It probably uses the same basic algorithm for 3D shading to determine how to color each square in the raster, but it might use a routine optimized for producing a 2D raster, instead of rasterizing a 3D plot. Note that `ReliefPlot` has an option `LightingAngle`. That and other language in the docs suggest that it produces a 2D rendering of a 3D surface. The `Method` option can be used to switching between two shading algorithms.

Comment: @Gravifer This might give a slightly closer reproduction, though the shadow transitions are still not a diffuse: `Plot3D[i + Sin[i^2 + j^2], {i, -4, 4}, {j, -4, 4}, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"][#3] &), PlotPoints -> 265, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[0.85]}, {"Directional", GrayLevel[0.25], ImageScaled[{-1, 1, Sqrt[2]}]}}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]`

Comment: I suspect what `ReliefPlot` is really doing is: (1) generate a 2D `DensityPlot`, embed it in the $xy$ plane in a `Graphics3D` box; the hue of the plot is now acquired; (2) compute the gradient vectors of the target function, use them to construct normal vectors for the (desired) surface: the actual surface is still a flat plane. The normals need not be really perpendicular to the gradient tangents; they just need to be in the same vertical plane. This effectively scales the target function in the $z$ direction. (3) normal mapping for the flat surface.

Comment: Also, the default-setting seems to use multiple sources for lighting (which you have gone to great lengths to replicate); but `ReliefPlot` only let you specify one 'effective' source at `LightingAngle -> {`$\theta$,$\phi$ `}`, yet still having a nice diffusion effect. One possibility is that the function uses a set of sources like in a photography studio, but I think we can agree this is hard to do. the `Method -> "DiffuseReflection"|"AspectBasedShading"` hints that it may use a flat surface with artificial normals instead of a legit 3D surface.

Comment: I found some relevant material [here](http://www.reliefshading.com/analytical/shading-methods/")

Comment: @MichealE2 also, even though the diffused reflection effect is gentle, the sharp results from real lighting on real surfaces can also be desired when one aim to imply details, so I don't think I can make an aesthetic choice for one over the other.

Comment: (continuing the 4th comment above) And as the surface is really flat, we don't really need the light source, but instead explicitly compute the cosine at each point. The computed shadow can then be masked upon the original `DensityPlot`

Answer (score 3):

**Update**
Found [this `ResourceFunction`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NormalTexture/); really nice touch.

---

As this is a guideline question, I'll place my own research in a standalone answer.
The ideas comes from the discussion with [@MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) under [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241351) following the `Plot3D` approach.

I mentioned there that it is possible do do artificial normal mapping and adding the shadow as a mask over the original `DensityPlot`. The following code is an example for how to do this:

```
theta=3Pi/4; phi=Pi/4;
func = j + Sin[i^2 + j^2];
base = DensityPlot[func, {i,-4, 4}, {j,-4, 4}, ColorFunction->"SunsetColors", PlotPoints->40];
shadow = Insert[
   DensityPlot[ 
     Evaluate[
       FromSphericalCoordinates[{1,theta,Pi-phi}](*Default source position of ReliefPlot*)
       . Normalize@Append[-Grad[func, {i, j}], 10](*2nd argument of GrayLevel is Opacity*)
     ], {i,-4, 4}, {j,-4, 4}, ColorFunction->(GrayLevel[#,(2#-1)^2]&), PlotPoints->80],
 Opacity[.5], {1, 1}];
GraphicsRow[{base, shadow,
  Show[{base, shadow}],
  ReliefPlot[Table[i + Sin[i^2 + j^2],
    {i,-4, 4, .03}, {j,-4, 4, .03}], ColorFunction->"SunsetColors"]}]
```

[image: mask approach result]
Note that:
(1) I switched `i` and `j` so the orientation matches.
(2) The $z$ component I appended to the `-Grad` vector is $10$ instead of $1$; this effectively shrinked the surface and smoothed the shadows. You may tweak this to achieve better visual effects.

The output is still isn't really quite the same to the built-in, but can show the gist of it.
I used a quadratic opacity scaling in the mask; it can be modified to improve the output.
What you need to know is that **in a true normal mapping, the shadow mask is multiplicative; a additive mask will never create highlight faithfully.**

Note that there are a few artifacts: the direction of the normal is somewhat 'singular' where the gradient vanishes.

---

Pack this to a single function (can be really buggy)

```
reliefPlot[f_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}, 
  ops : OptionsPattern[{LightingAngle -> {(3 \[Pi])/4, \[Pi]/4}, 
     DensityPlot, ReliefPlot}]] := 
 Show[{DensityPlot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, ops], 
   Insert[DensityPlot[ 
     Evaluate[
      FromSphericalCoordinates[{1, 
         OptionValue[LightingAngle][[1]], \[Pi] - 
          OptionValue[LightingAngle][[-1]]}] . 
       Normalize@Append[-Grad[f, {x, y}], 10]], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, 
      ymin, ymax}, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#, (2 # - 1)^2] &), 
     Evaluate[Sequence @@ FilterRules[{ops}, PlotPoints]]], 
    Opacity[.5], {1, 1}]}]
```