# Checking membership of 2d region

Tags: list-manipulation, intervals

I want to check whether a point $(x,y)$ belongs to a square region whose x-interval is $[x_1,x_2]$ and y-interval is $[y_1,y_2]$. I defined the 2d region as

```
Interval[{{x1,x2},{y1,y2}}]
```

and checked for membership as

```
IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{{x1,x2},{y1,y2}}],{x,y}]
```

but the output is always {False, False} no matter the input. For example

```
IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{{0,1},{0,1}}],{0.5,0.5}]
{False,False} (*output*)
```

What is going wrong? What is the correct way to deal with this problem? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `Interval` is strictly 1D. Do `RegionMember[ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}], {0.5, 0.5}]`.

Comment: @Kuba , corey979 Unfortunately Mathematica 9.0 does not seem to have that function.

Comment: There are some older topics: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9405/5478

Comment: @Kuba Thank you very much. I shall check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Interval` is for 1-dimensional regions only. For a 2D region, one can do

```
RegionMember[ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}], {0.5, 0.5}]
```

> True

or, in pre-`RegionMember` versions, by threading over each dimension with

```
MapThread[IntervalMemberQ, {{Interval[{0, 1}], Interval[{0, 1}]}, {0.5, 0.5}}]
```

> {True, True}

To get a definite answer, apply `And`:

```
And @@ MapThread[IntervalMemberQ, {{Interval[{0, 1}], Interval[{0, 1}]}, {0.5, 0.5}}]
```

> True

Contrary, with `{0.5, 1.5}`:

```
MapThread[IntervalMemberQ, {{Interval[{0, 1}], Interval[{0, 1}]}, {0.5, 1.5}}]
```

> {True, False}

so that

```
And @@ MapThread[IntervalMemberQ, {{Interval[{0, 1}], Interval[{0, 1}]}, {0.5, 1.5}}]
```

> False