# Create piecewise f[x,y] from functions with intersecting domains

Tags: piecewise

I have two functions `f1` and `f2`. They have a square region in the $x-y$ plane as their domain. They might intersect, or they might not. Example:

```
f1["Domain"]
f2["Domain"]
(* {{-480., -180.}, {68., 268.}} *)
(* {{-729., -429.}, {68., 268.}} *)
```

I want to create a piecewise function that is defined by the following characteristics. For every point `{x0, y0}`:

- if in exclusive `f1` domain, return `f1[$x_0,y_0$]`,
- if in exclusive `f2` domain, return `f2[$x_0,y_0$]`,
- if in intersection, return `Max[f1[$x_0,y_0$],f2[$x_0,y_0$]]`,
- if elsewhere, return `0`.

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: See also [Checking membership of 2d region](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131378/checking-membership-of-2d-region).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f1domain = {{-480., -180.}, {68., 268.}};
f2domain = {{-729., -429.}, {68., 268.}};

reg1 = ImplicitRegion[
 LessEqual @@ Riffle[First@f1domain, x] && LessEqual @@ Riffle[Last@f1domain, y],
       {x, y}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[
 LessEqual @@ Riffle[First@f2domain, x] && LessEqual @@ Riffle[Last@f2domain, y],
       {x, y}];

RegionPlot@{reg1, reg2}
```

[image]

```
v[x0_, y0_] := 
 Which[
  RegionMember[RegionDifference[reg1, reg2], {x0, y0}], 
   f1[x0, y0],
  RegionMember[RegionDifference[reg2, reg1], {x0, y0}], 
   f2[x0, y0],
  RegionMember[RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2], {x0, y0}], 
   Max@{f1[x0, y0], f2[x0, y0]}, 
  Not@RegionMember[RegionUnion[reg1, reg2], {x0, y0}],
   0
 ]

v[-600, 150]
v[-300, 150]
v[-450, 150]
v[-450, 1500]
```

> f2[-600, 150]
>
> f1[-300, 150]
>
> Max[f1[-450, 150], f2[-450, 150]]
>
> 0

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As a further question, if you do not mind, I would like to know the following: How can I write a module that accepts f1 and f2 and returns v? Having a hard time with this one. I want to keep "stitching" more functions using this module.

Comment: You'd have to create the regions and `Which` beforehand. With `f1domain` replaced with `f1["Domain"]`, sth like `func[x0_,y0_,f1_,f2_,...]:=Module[{reg1,reg2,...,v},v[x0_,y0_]:=...,reg1=...;reg2=...;v[x0,y0]]`