# How to select points from a table that are within some region

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, conditional

there, I encountered this problem while coding:

I generate a table in the r-z plane of cylindrical coordinates:

```
tbl = Flatten[Table[{r, z}, {r, 0, 1, .1}, {z, -.8, .8, .1}], 1];
```

and the boundary curve of the region is defined parametrically in the bispherical coordinates:

```
r[η_, ξ_] := (c Sin[η])/(Cosh[ξ] - Cos[η]);
z[η_, ξ_] := (c Sinh[ξ])/(Cosh[ξ] - Cos[η]);
```

with the constant:

```
c = ρ Sin[η0];(*ρ Sin[η0]*)
ρ = (2/(3 (π - η0) Cos[η0] + 3 Sin[η0] - 
  Sin[η0]^3))^(1/3);
```

Thus, given the fixed `η0`, such as `η0=π/3`, plot the curve:

```
η0=Pi/3;
ParametricPlot[{r[η0, ξ], z[η0, ξ]}, {ξ, -30, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I want to select the points that lie inside of the region bounded by the curve and the y-axis, but I don't know how to add this condition to "Select". Please help!

Comment: Your curve isn't closed. I assume you want to bound the region with $x>0$ ?

Comment: yes, sorry, I didn't describe it correctly, I want the points inside of the region bounded by the curve and the y-axis

Comment: Look up `RegionFunction` and define your region by statements such as $0<x<1.2$ and $-X(x) < y < + X(x)$, where $X(x)$ is derived from you implicit equations.  Once you have a region function you can use `RegionMember` applied to each point.

Comment: Alternativly to Vitaliy's answer, you could also solve the equation to a $y(x)$ function as mentioned by David with `xiSols = Normal[Solve[x == r[\[Eta]0, xi], xi, Reals]]
ySol = z[\[Eta]0, xi] /. xiSols // Simplify`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(9405)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9405/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested i present an alternative solution.

But keep in mind, this depends on the ability to solve your implicit equations and therefore, does not work everytime. But when it works it yields a fast Boolean condition.

We doing the following. Consider your set of equations, depending on the parameter $\xi$.

$$(x,y)=(r(\xi),z(\xi))$$

We solve the first one for the parameter and plug this solution into the other equation. 
We hope to not only solve this, but to get at least 2 equations which bound your region in $y(x)$.

$$\xi=r^{-1}(x)\\
y(x)=z(r^{-1}(x))$$

We can get the $r^{-1}$ with

```
xiSols=Normal[Solve[x==r[\[Eta]0,xi],xi,Reals]]
```

which has two solutions. So we've already won.
Plug this into the second equation:

```
{ySolL,ySolR}=z[\[Eta]0,xi]/.xiSols//Simplify
```

The sign signals us that `ySolL < ySolR` and therefore `ySolL < y < ySolR`

We can easily check this:

```
RegionPlot[ySolL<=y<=ySolR,{x,0,1.2},{y,-1,1}]
```

> [image: regionplot]

So you could now either:

- create a region and check with [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html)
- Use the fast Boolean condition directly `ySolL<=y<=ySolR && x > 0`

  `tblIn=Select[tbl,(ySolL<=y<=ySolR&&x>=0)/.{x->#[[1]],y->#[[2]]}&];`

  With the plot

  `Show[RegionPlot[ySolL <= y <= ySolR, {x, 0, 1.2}, {y, -1, 1}], 
  ListPlot[tblIn]]`

  > [image: Blockquote]

Comment: +1. The lack of an upper limit on $x$ becomes a problem if there are points to the right of the region though.

Answer (score 8):

You should parametrize your region. `c` looks to me like sort of a radius and it will help to cut off half a plane.

```
tbl=Flatten[Table[{r,z},{r,0,1,.1},{z,-.8,.8,.1}],1];

r[η_,ξ_, c_]:=(c Sin[η])/(Cosh[ξ]-Cos[η]);
z[η_,ξ_, c_]:=(c Sinh[ξ])/(Cosh[ξ]-Cos[η]);

η0=Pi/3;
ρ=(2/(3 (π-η0) Cos[η0]+3 Sin[η0]-Sin[η0]^3))^(1/3);
c0=ρ Sin[η0];

rig = Region[ParametricRegion[{{r[η0, ξ, c], z[η0, ξ, c]}, 
    0 < c < c0}, {{ξ, -30, 30}, c}], Epilog -> Point[tbl]]
```

[image]

```
sel=Select[tbl,RegionMember[rig,#]&];

Region[ParametricRegion[{{r[η0,ξ,c],z[η0,ξ,c]},0<c<c0},
{{ξ,-30,30},c}],Epilog->Point[sel]]
```

[image]

I am not sure why some points look they slightly sticking out of the region, - might be drawing imprecision or an issue. You should check this as I am out of time, I hope it's a start.

Comment: beat me by just 1 minute.

Comment: @JulienKluge it is always a race here ;-)

Comment: Many appreciations to both of you!

Comment: @Julien Kluge can you please also post your answer if you're not using the same method?

Comment: @JulienKluge yes if you are doing something else feel free to post.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I tried to run your code on my computer, but, what is this `Region` function? What does it do?  I can't find it in the Wolfram Documentation, and my current version is 10.4

Comment: @YingZhang I use 11.2. It just shows a region. Use PlotRegion then.

Comment: @YingZhang And you can always check online docs: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Oh, got it! Thanks!!