# Check if a curve is contained in a region

Tags: regions, expression-test, boolean-computation, polygons

Let's consider a curve described by a function $y = f(x)$ as well as a region $\mathcal{R}$ (consider that this region can be complicated) described by a set of points $\mathcal{X} = (x_{i,1},x_{i,2})$. I need to build a function which returns $0$ if $\exists x$ | $(x,f(x)) \in \mathcal{R}$ and returns 1 else. As I need to map this function over a large list (size > $10^5$), it has to be computationally efficient. Let say we have a `R = RegularPolygon[5]` and `f[x_] = x^2` it is simple to see that the curve is contained in $\mathcal{R}$, as shown in the following Figure :

[image]

For now, I made several pieces of code, but none is qualified in terms of calculation speed and precision.

The initial code :

```
X = {{-0.58, -0.80}, {-0.95, 0.30}, {0, 1}, {0.95, 0.30}, {0.58, -0.8}};
R = Polygon@X;
PR = N@RegionBounds[R];
f[x_] = x^2;
P1 = Graphics[R, Frame -> True];
P2 = Plot[f[x], {x, PR[[1, 1]], PR[[1, 2]]}, PlotStyle -> Orange];
Show[P1, P2]
```

Variant 1 : discretize the curve and `RegionMember`

```
TheFunction[R_, f_] := Module[{Pts, Test},
Pts = Table[{i, f[i]}, {i, PR[[1, 1]], PR[[1, 2]], 
 Abs[PR[[1, 1]] - PR[[1, 2]]]/1000}];
Test = RegionMember[R, Pts];
Boole@Not@MemberQ[Test, True] (*If one point is contained, return 0*)]
TheFunction[R, f] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.4362, 0}*)
```

Variant 2 : discretize the curve and solution of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405/how-to-check-if-a-2d-point-is-in-a-polygon)

```
inPolyQ[poly_, pt_] := Graphics`PolygonUtils`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] =!= 0
TheFunction[R_, f_] := Module[{Pts, Test},
Pts = Table[{i, f[i]}, {i, PR[[1, 1]], PR[[1, 2]], 
Abs[PR[[1, 1]] - PR[[1, 2]]]/1000}];
Boole@NoneTrue[Pts, inPolyQ[R, #] &]]
TheFunction[R, f] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.0014816, 0}*)
```

One notices that Variant 2 yields quicker results than Variant 1. One major drawback of the two variants is the discretization of the curve which impacts the precision.

Any idea to avoid this discretization ? Symbolic calculation, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the border of the region consists of a number of curves. For a simple  example I take a polygon that is bordered by lines. We may then analytically check if there is some point common to the given curve and any border curve:

```
f[x_] = x^2;
pts = CirclePoints[5]; AppendTo[pts, pts[[1]]];
lines = Partition[pts, 2, 1];
AnyTrue[FindInstance[{x, f[x]} == #[[1]] + lam (#[[2]] - #[[1]])&& 0 <= lam <= 1, {x, 
     lam}, Reals] & /@ lines, # != {} &]

True
```

To check if this work, we add 10 to the curve:

```
f[x_] = x^2 + 10;
AnyTrue[FindInstance[{x, f[x]} == #[[1]] + lam (#[[2]] - #[[1]]), {x, 
     lam}, Reals] & /@ lines, # != {} &]

False
```

Comment: Your solution is interesting because it's analytical. However, have you tried f(x) = x^2+1.1? The function returns True even though the curve is not contained in the region.

Comment: You are right. The trouble was, that the function checked only  if there is a common point on any line. However, the commen point must be between the 2 points defining the line. I added this additional test.

Comment: As the region I'm using in my large-scale problem is ALWAYS defined by a polygon, your updated solution is very precise and fast enough for my practical application which involves Monte-Carlo processes. I'll accept your answer, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5):

For precision, you could try RegionDisjoint with a ParametricRegion for the curve. E.g.,

```
RegionDisjoint[
    ParametricRegion[{x,x^2},{{x,-1,1}}],
    RegularPolygon[5]
]
```

replacing RegularPolygon[5] with any other 2D region, and replacing x^2 in ParametricRegion with your function f[x] and adjusting the range of x, e.g., to extend at least to the horizontal bounds of your 2D region.

This is simple code, but may be too slow for complicated curves or 2D regions.

Answer (score 2):

For precison,maybe use `MinValue` of the `RegionDistance` of the curve to the polygon.

```
dist = RegionDistance[R];
MinValue[dist@{x, f[x]}, 0.69728719 <= x <= 1, x] > 0 // Boole
MinValue[dist@{x, f[x]}, 0.69728720 <= x <= 1, x] > 0 // Boole
```

> `0`

> `1`

- The endpoint of the curve is inside or outside of the polygon can be illustrate in the figure as below.

```
pt0 = {x, f[x]} /. x -> 0.69728719;
pt1 = {x, f[x]} /. x -> 0.69728720;
Plot[f[x], {x, 0.69728719, 0.69728720}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[pt0], Point[pt1], 
   Opacity[.2], Green, BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@R}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Reduce[Rationalize[{x, f[x]} ∈ R && -.1 <= x <= 1, 0], 
  x] // AbsoluteTiming`